# No module named _sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, debian, python-import

I am trying to run a [Django](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Django_%28web_framework%29) app on my [VPS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_private_server) running [Debian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debian#Releases) 5. When I run a demo app, it comes back with this error:

```
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/utils/importlib.py", line 35, in     import_module
    __import__(name)

  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/site-packages/django/db/backends/sqlite3/base.py", line 30, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured, "Error loading %s: %s" % (module, exc)

ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading either pysqlite2 or sqlite3 modules (tried in that     order): No module named _sqlite3
```

Looking at the Python install, it gives the same error:

```
Python 2.5.2 (r252:60911, May 12 2009, 07:46:31) 
[GCC 4.1.2 20061115 (prerelease) (Debian 4.1.1-21)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import sqlite3
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/sqlite3/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from dbapi2 import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.5/sqlite3/dbapi2.py", line 27, in <module>
    from _sqlite3 import *
ImportError: No module named _sqlite3
>>>
```

Reading on the web, I learn that Python 2.5 should come with all the necessary [SQLite](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) wrappers included. Do I need to reinstall Python, or is there another way to get this module up and running?

Comment: Same problem is for compiled python 3.5.5 from source

Answer (score 279):

It seems your makefile didn't include the appropriate `.so` file. You can correct this problem with the steps below:

1. Install `sqlite-devel` (or `libsqlite3-dev` on some Debian-based systems)
2. Re-configure and re-compiled Python with `./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && sudo make install`

---

**Note**

The `sudo make install` part will set that python version to be the system-wide standard, which can have unforseen consequences. If you run this command on your workstation, you'll probably want to have it installed *alongside* the existing python, which can be done with [`sudo make altinstall`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018463/difference-in-details-between-make-install-and-make-altinstall).

Comment: Thanks jammyWolf. I don't think that I "lost" the file after the first time that I  ran configure, rather, that running configure with sqlite-devel already installed made all of this difference.

Comment: The configuration saved me "./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions"

Comment: How can I install ```sqlite-devel``` ? I'm on a customized linux system.I just downloaded ```sqlite-autoconf-3100200.tar.gz``` and run ```./configure```,```make && make install```. After I recompile python3 it's still not working.

Comment: For anyone reading this, make sure to add the configure option in the answer. That's what saved me too. Otherwise it won't matter that you've installed libsqlite3-dev.

Comment: how do I check where the configure script is?

Comment: Thanks for that. Also followed the following reddit post to compile Python: https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/comments/5unkb3/install_sqlite3_on_python_3/ddzdz2b/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I only had to re-download and execute `./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && sudo make install` Worked!

Comment: I am using `pyenv` and after installing `libsqlite3-dev` I had to re-install your python version with `pyenv install <python-version>`.

Comment: I had to install libsqlite3-dev on ubuntu 14.04, followed by step 2. Worked like a charm - thank you.

Comment: If I use `python 3,6 ` mean to say `pipenv --python 3.6` when creating the virtual environment then the problem gets solved.

Comment: none of these solutions (ref: all on this page) work for amazon linux with python 3.8.0

Comment: Continued to fail for me because I had built sqlite3 in a custom dir. To fix I had to edit Python3's setup.py file. Look for sqlite_inc_paths assignment. Add your sqlite3 include dir to the list. That's was my last stumbling block.

Comment: For the actual working name (Debian-based distros), search for sqlite3 and dev packages like: `sudo apt-cache search sqlite3 | grep dev`, then you will find the "correct" name. For me it was `libsqlite3-dev` thus I did **`sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev`**

Comment: This works for me. Centos 8, python 3.8.8
follow this one to install python3.8 https://computingforgeeks.com/how-to-install-python-3-on-centos/

1. execute `yum install sqlite-devel`
2. go to the python source code(where you download)
Re-configure and re-compiled Python with `./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions && make && sudo make install`

Comment: Works with pytho3.10 & RedHat 8.5.

Comment: I had install python3.8, and beause this problem I reinstall python3.8 as above, and then my system have two python3.8, one of that contain sqlite3 and another not contain sqlite3, @AntiMoron ,"whereis python" can get python path

Comment: Im using python3.7.13 on redhat linux distribution on Aws. Is there specific version of `sqlite-devel` that I need to install? I need to send info to another team so they can install for me.

Comment: Worked for me to install Python 3.12.2 on Ubuntu 20.04. I have followed the tutorial https://www.howtogeek.com/install-latest-python-version-on-ubuntu/ and have adapted one line based on this answer: `./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions`

Answer (score 101):

I had the same problem with Python 3.5 on Ubuntu while using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv).

If you're installing the python using [pyenv](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv), it's listed as one of the [common build problems](https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems). To solve it, remove the installed python version, install the requirements (for this particular case `libsqlite3-dev`), then reinstall the python version with

```
pyenv install <python-version>
```

Then recreate virtualenv if needed.

Comment: It's not required to remove the installed version, `pyenv install <python-version>` will ask whether it should be overridden and re-compiles.

Comment: I used pyenv too and this works for me. Have to reinstall the whole environment so that the change will take effect. Remember to install libsqlite3-dev before that.

Answer (score 87):

I had the same problem (building `python2.5` from source on Ubuntu Lucid), and `import sqlite3` threw this same exception. I've installed `libsqlite3-dev` from the package manager, recompiled python2.5, and then the import worked.

Comment: Exactly! You don't have to manually manipulate with binary files and environment. In my case I had already Python 2.7 built from source, so, to minify compilation I've executed

    apt-get install libsqlite3-dev;
    ./configure;
    make libinstall;
    make sharedinstall;

Answer (score 39):

my python is build from source, the cause is missing options when exec configure
python version：3.7.4

```
./configure --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions --enable-optimizations
make
make install
```

fixed

Comment: Didn't work. bash: ./configure: No such file or directory

Comment: i mean execute this command in the python source directory, like this:https://github.com/python/cpython

Comment: You should cd to your python source directory and in the directory use the `./configure` command @QuangHoàngMinh

Answer (score 32):

1. Install the `sqlite-devel` package:

   `yum install sqlite-devel -y`
2. Recompile python from the source:

   ```
   ./configure
   make
   make altinstall
   ```

Comment: I did 1(yum install sqlite-devl -y) this was okay. in #2, I got this err `bash: ./configure: No such file or directory`. How can I fix.

Comment: Taking a lot of time on make command. What exactly this does? Is it recompiling the centOS kernel or what?

Comment: This worked for me, I'm using CENTOs 7, and Python 3.8.14. Thank you.

Answer (score 31):

This is what I did to get it to work.

I am using pythonbrew(which is using pip) with python 2.7.5 installed.

I first did what Zubair(above) said and ran this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Then I ran this command:

```
pip install pysqlite
```

This fixed the database problem and I got confirmation of this when I ran:

```
python manager.py syncdb
```

Comment: in Centos 6.5 run `yum install sqlite-devel` instead of the first line.

Comment: That's good for Python 2, but `pysqlite` is now `sqlite3` in Python 3, and you can't `pip -m install` that.

Comment: `pysqlite is not supported on Python 3. When using Python 3, use the sqlite3 module from the standard library`

Comment: @Joe I think it should be manage.py instead of manager.py

Answer (score 22):

For Python 3.7.8 with Redhat 7 or Centos 7.

- Install sqlite-devel

```sh
$ yum install sqlite-devel
```

- Compile and install Python3 with **sqllite extensions**

```
$ ./configure --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
$ make install
```

Comment: can confirm this works with 3.10.8

Comment: This also worked on Amazon Linux 2 base image, thanks!

Answer (score 14):

I found lots of people meet this problem because the Multi-version Python,
on my own vps (cent os 7 x64), I solved it in this way:

1. Find the file "_sqlite3.so"

   ```
   find / -name _sqlite3.so
   ```

   out:  `/usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so`
2. Find the dir of python Standard library you want to use,

   for me `/usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload`
3. Copy the file:

   ```
   cp   /usr/lib64/python2.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload
   ```

Finally, everything will be ok.

Comment: Didn't work for me. Got `ImportError: dynamic module does not define module export function (PyInit__sqlite3)` on CentOS 7.

Comment: same to me, is that py2 `.so` can't be used for py3.6.4? @xtluo

Comment: I got this error instead - `ImportError: libpython2.7.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`

Comment: Seems to work for me: sudo cp /usr/lib64/python3.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so /usr/local/lib/python3.7/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so. Now I can run tensorboard without the _sqlite3 error! Thx

Answer (score 11):

My _sqlite3.so is in /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so.  Judging from your paths, you should have the file /usr/local/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so.

Try the following:

```
find /usr/local -name _sqlite3.so
```

If the file isn't found, something may be wrong with your Python installation.  If it is, make sure the path it's installed to is in the Python path.  In the Python shell,

```
import sys
print sys.path
```

In my case, /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload is in the list, so it's able to find /usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so.

Comment: just checked. the path is in there, but _sqlite3.so is indeed missing. Any suggestions whether i can seperately install it or better to reinstall python? thx!

Comment: It looks like you built and installed Python manually (are the packages in your OS too old?), since it's in /usr/local.  Make sure that the sqlite dev package is installed (libsqlite3-dev in current distros, maybe not in yours), or Python won't be able to build the module.  If you install it, you'll need to rebuild Python so it includes that module.

Comment: Hmm, I installed libsqlite3-dev and rebuild python, but now i get anothe error:

    ImportError: ./_sqlite3.so: undefined symbol: PyUnicodeUCS4_DecodeUTF8

Comment: I'm confused.  Your distro has Python 2.5 already (http://packages.debian.org/lenny/python2.5).  Why are you building it yourself?

Comment: ah, sorry, wrong choice of words. in fact i re-installed python2.5 via apt-get.

Comment: But you're running Python out of /usr/local.  It looks like you installed Python twice--once yourself and once with apt-get, and the one in /usr/local is broken.

Answer (score 9):

I recently tried installing python 2.6.7 on my Ubuntu 11.04 desktop for some dev work. Came across similar problems to this thread. I mamaged to fix it by:

1. Adjusting the setup.py file to include the correct sqlite dev path. Code snippet from setup.py:

   ```
   def sqlite_incdir:
   sqlite_dirs_to_check = [
   os.path.join(sqlite_incdir, '..', 'lib64'),
   os.path.join(sqlite_incdir, '..', 'lib'),
   os.path.join(sqlite_incdir, '..', '..', 'lib64'),
   os.path.join(sqlite_incdir, '..', '..', 'lib'),
   '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'
   ]
   ```

   With the bit that I added being '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/'.
2. After running make I did not get any warnings saying the sqlite support was not built (i.e., it built correctly :P ), but after running `make install`, sqlite3 still did not import with the same "`ImportError: No module named _sqlite3" whe running "import sqlite3`".

   So, the library was compiled, but not moved to the correct installation path, so I copied the `.so` file (`cp /usr/src/python/Python-2.6.7/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.6/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/python-2.6.7/lib/python2.6/sqlite3/` — these are my build paths, you will probably need to adjust them to your setup).

Voila! SQLite3 support now works.

Comment: Thank you! Just the first part was needed for Linux Mint Debian Edition, 2014

Comment: Thank you! Exactly same problem for me. The library is built but not copied to the right directory.

Answer (score 8):

This worked for me in Redhat Centos 6.5:

```
yum install sqlite-devel
pip install pysqlite
```

Comment: just fyi I did not need to do the pip step

Comment: ```pip install pysqlite3-binary``` worked instead of ```pip install pysqlite3```

Answer (score 5):

`sqlite3` ships with Python. I also had the same problem, I just uninstalled `python3.6` and installed it again.

Uninstall existing python:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge python3.6
```

Install python3.6:

```
sudo apt install build-essential checkinstall
sudo apt install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.0/Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
tar xvf Python-3.6.0.tar.xz
cd Python-3.6.0/
./configure
sudo make altinstall
```

Comment: Works well on Debian Buster

Answer (score 4):

Is the [python-pysqlite2](http://packages.debian.org/lenny/python-pysqlite2) package installed?

```
sudo apt-get install python-pysqlite2
```

Comment: sqlite is installed with Python; you don't need to install a separate package for it, and we can tell that he does already have the Python-supplied library.  Installing python-sqlite would be confusing at best.

Comment: Brain cramp. I meant the python-pysqlite2 package. I could not get Django/sqlite to work on lenny without this package. I've updated my answer.

Comment: I have python-pysqlite2 installed.

Answer (score 4):

Checking your settings.py file.
Did you not just write "sqlite" instead of "sqlite3" for the database engine?

Answer (score 4):

i got the same problem, nothing worked for me from the above ans
but now i fixed it by

just remove python.pip and sqlite3 and reinstall

1. sudo apt-get remove python.pip
2. sudo apt-get remove sqlite3

now install it again

3. sudo apt-get install python.pip
4. sudo apt-get install sqlite3

in my case while installing sqlite3 again it showed some error
then i typed

5. sqlite3

on terminal to check if it was removed or not and it started unpacking it

once the sqlite3 is installed
fireup terminal and write

6. sqlite3
7. database.db (to create a database)
   i'm sure this will definately help you

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu, Python 3.7.10, Jupyter 6.1.5

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem after installing Python 3.8.11 using [asdf](https://asdf-vm.com/)

To fix the issue:

I had to install `libsqlite3-dev`

```
sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
```

Then uninstall Python via `asdf`

```
asdf uninstall python 3.8.11
```

And install Python again via `asdf`

```
asdf install python 3.8.11
```

Answer (score 3):

Putting answer for anyone who lands on this page searching for a solution for Windows OS:

You have to install pysqlite3 or db-sqlite3 if not already installed. you can use following to install.

- pip install pysqlite3
- pip install db-sqlite3

For me the issue was with DLL file of sqlite3.

Solution:

1. I took DLL file from [sqlite site](https://www.sqlite.org/download.html). This might vary based on your
   version of python installation.
2. I pasted it in the DLL directory of
   the env. for me it was "C:\Anaconda\Lib\DLLs", but check for yours.
   [image: Before and After placing DLL file]

Comment: I had the exact error. This somehow solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I was disappointed this issue still exist till today. As I have recently been trying to install vCD CLI on CentOS 8.1 and I was welcomed with the same error when tried to run it. The way I had to resolve it in my case is as follow:

- Install SQLite3 from scratch with the proper prefix
- Make clean my Python Installation
- Run Make install to reinstall Python

As I have been doing this to create a different blogpost about how to install vCD CLI and VMware Container Service Extension. I have end up capturing the steps I used to fix the issue and put it in a separate blog post at:

http://www.virtualizationteam.com/cloud/running-vcd-cli-fail-with-the-following-error-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-_sqlite3.html

I hope this helpful, as while the tips above had helped me get to a solution, I had to combine few of them and modify them a bit.

Comment: Thank you for disclosing your affiliation with the link you are providing! It is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The following worked for Python 3.9 with a virtual environment:

1. Install the sqlite3 library.

   ```sh
   sudo apt-get install libsqlite3-dev
   ```
2. Activate the Python virtual environment.

   ```sh
   source env/bin/activate
   ```
3. Copy the sqlite3 file into the Python virtual environment and rename it to support Python 3.9.

   ```sh
   cp /usr/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ./env/lib/python3.9/site-packages
   mv ./env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_sqlite3.cpython-38-x86_64-linux-gnu.so ./env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/_sqlite3.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
   ```

*Note, we're renaming 38 to 39 in the file name to support Python 3.9.*

Answer (score 2):

I have the  problem in FreeBSD 8.1:

```
- No module named _sqlite3 -
```

It is solved by stand the port ----------

```
/usr/ports/databases/py-sqlite3
```

after this one can see:

```
OK ----------
'>>>' import sqlite3 -----
'>>>' sqlite3.apilevel -----
'2.0'
```

Comment: This answer makes very little sense. Can you revise it?

Comment: I had same issue, FreeBSD 8.2 w/Py2.7.2.    Resolved by just running through make/install again, for py-sqlite3.

Comment: you have to make deinstall if it seems installed at first. freebsd 10.2

Answer (score 2):

you must be in centos or redhat and compile python yourself，
it is python‘s bug
do this in your python source code dir and do this below

```
curl -sk https://gist.github.com/msabramo/2727063/raw/59ea097a1f4c6f114c32f7743308a061698b17fd/gistfile1.diff | patch -p1
```

Answer (score 2):

Try installing sqlite like this if you are using FreeBSD.

```
pkg install py27-sqlite3-2.7.10_6
```

Answer (score 1):

I faced this issue with multiple python dependent package while setup in python virtual enironment in **Ubuntu**.It is because of **sqlite** binding for our **python**.

**Error I got**:

```
    from pysqlite2 import dbapi2 as sqlite3
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pysqlite2'
```

I resolved it by --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions=yes
1.) First find your python or python version you used for creating virtual env. I have used python3.8
e.g

```
$ whereis python
python: /usr/bin/python3.6m /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/python3.8 /usr/bin/python2.7-config /usr/bin/python3.8-config  python

$ cd /usr/bin

$ls
python3.8
python3.8-config
```

**Note:** there will be many package check for pytho. you will find configure file for each python version, now use specific python version

```
ox:/usr/bin$ ./python3.8-config --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions=yes
```

OR

```
ox:/usr/bin$ ./python3.8-config --enable-optimizations --enable-loadable-sqlite-extensions
```

Now, create your virtual env using that python version
e.g
Go the folder where you want to create the virtual env

```
$ python3.8 -m venv mlwen_jup_env
$ source mlwen_jup_env/bin/activate
```

Its done, now you can install packages

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same problem on a NetBSD server. A missing `.so` file needed to be installed using `pkgin`. To identify what package to install, I ran

```
pkgin search sqlite
```

which had lots of results, including

```
...

py38-aiosqlite-0.17.0nb1  Async bridge to the standard sqlite3 module
py38-apsw-3.37.0nb2  Python wrapper for SQLite
py38-peewee-3.15.0   Small, expressive ORM for PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite
py38-sqlite3-3.8.13nb22  Built-in sqlite support for Python 2.5 and up
py39-aiosqlite-0.17.0nb1  Async bridge to the standard sqlite3 module
py39-apsw-3.37.0nb2  Python wrapper for SQLite
py39-peewee-3.15.0   Small, expressive ORM for PostgreSQL, MySQL and SQLite
py39-sqlite3-3.9.13nb22  Built-in sqlite support for Python 2.5 and up
...
```

(and other python versions as well). I'm using python 3.9, so `py39-sqlite3-3.9.13nb22` was the correct choice in my case. Running

```
sudo pkgin install py39-sqlite3-3.9.13nb22
```

fixed the issue for me.

Comment: pkgin: command not found

Comment: NetBSD does not necessarily come with `pkgin` preinstalled. This page has the official instructions for installing `pkg_add` and then `pkgin`: https://www.netbsd.org/docs/pkgsrc/using.html

Answer (score 1):

I resolved reinstalling Python `pyenv install <version>` and then `pyenv rehash`. Without destroying any previously created virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

I am using Ubuntu with Python3.9 and a venv. I had the same issue.
first I installed pysqlite

```bash
pip install pysqlite3
```

but it was installed in the `/home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysqlite3`

then I moved it to the local dir

```bash
mv /home/<user>/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pysqlite3 /usr/local/lib/python3.9/sqlite3
```

pay attention to the name change from `pysqlite3` to `sqlite3`

Answer (score 0):

Download sqlite3:

```
wget http://www.sqlite.org/2016/sqlite-autoconf-3150000.tar.gz
```

Follow these steps to install:

```
$tar xvfz sqlite-autoconf-3071502.tar.gz
$cd sqlite-autoconf-3071502
$./configure --prefix=/usr/local
$make install
```

Comment: This question was asked in 2009 and was about Debian 5. sqlite3 is now [available in the repos](https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/sqlite3) (since Wheezy) so there is no need to install it manually. I guess this is true for most distros as well.

Answer (score -3):

You need to install [pysqlite](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysqlite) in your python environment:

```
    $ pip install pysqlite
```

Answer (score -4):

Try copying `_sqlite3.so` so that Python can find it.

It should be as simple as:

```
cp /usr/lib64/python2.6/lib-dynload/_sqlite3.so /usr/local/lib/python2.7/
```

Trust me, try it.