# UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, anaconda, ipython, history

On Ubuntu, using Anaconda (miniconda3), when starting IPython I get the warning "UserWarning: IPython History requires SQLite, your history will not be saved". And as it says, the history doesn't work.

I have read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14173271/warning-ipython-history-requires-sqlite-your-history-will-not-be-saved) but it's old, it's for macOS, and it's too complicated.

Is there a simple way to fix the problem and get the history working?

---

```
$ conda list ipython
# packages in environment at /home/j/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
ipython                   7.13.0           py37h5ca1d4c_0  
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                    py37_0  

$ conda list sqlite
# packages in environment at /home/j/miniconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
sqlite                    3.31.1               h62c20be_1
```

Comment: Can you give us the output of `conda list ipython` and `conda list sqlite`?

Comment: @cel I added the outputs above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a very easy solution:

```
conda install sqlite
conda uninstall ipython
conda install ipython
```