# How to Fix Python Nose: Coverage not available: unable to import coverage module

Tags: python, nose, coverage.py, python-coverage

I can't seem to get code coverage with Nose to work, despite having the plugin installed.

Any ideas on how to fix this?

```
12:15:25 ~/sandbox/ec$ nosetests --plugins
Plugin xunit
Plugin deprecated
Plugin skip
Plugin multiprocess
Plugin failuredetail
Plugin capture
Plugin logcapture
Plugin coverage
Plugin attributeselector
Plugin doctest
Plugin profile
Plugin id
Plugin allmodules
Plugin collect-only
Plugin isolation
Plugin pdb

12:15:34 ~/sandbox/ec$ nosetests -v --with-coverage
nose.plugins.cover: ERROR: Coverage not available: unable to import coverage module
tests.edgecast_client_tests.test_log ... ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 1 test in 0.206s

OK
```

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Have you tried `pip install coverage`? The coverage plugin depends on separate coverage module, which is not a nose's dependency, so needs to be installed manually.

Comment: on debian/ubuntu you could install via `apt-get install python-coverage` as well

Comment: I've installed it both ways and it still gives me the same error.

Comment: I received the same error in the original question even though I have the coverage package installed in my virtualenv.  My problem was that the nosetests command was coming from my system-wide installation of nose, and I didn't have coverage installed system-wide.   By prepending the full path to the executable in my virtualenv, /path/to/virtualenv/bin/nosetests --with-coverage worked.

Comment: @velotron Strangely, the same solution worked for me despite the fact that I don't have a system-wide installation of nose

Comment: @mnagel  @Diego You may need to use `apt-get install python3-coverage` if you have Python3.

Comment: @velotron I tried installing `nose` into my virtualenv (along with `coverage`), which seemed to work.

Comment: My virtualenv has python3.4.2. I did `pip install coverage` and the issue went away. So the accepted answer worked for me.

Comment: Updating both packages `pip install coverage -U` and `pip install nose -U` did it for me. But with older nose (1.3.0) I am getting coverage (4.0.3) that shows me which line numbers are not covered.

Answer (score 3):

Validate if the coverage module is working by itself via `coverage --version`. I had a case that it was not working due to the lack of SQLite modules in my python installation from the source. I reinstalled python with SQLite extension to fix the issue.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1210664/no-module-named-sqlite3/38842600#38842600 for details when using `pyenv`.