# Difference in details between "make install" and "make altinstall"

Tags: makefile, installation

Here is my case:

I am using [Ubuntu 10.04](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_version_history#Ubuntu_10.04_LTS_.28Lucid_Lynx.29) (Lucid Lynx). The system's default Python is v2.6.5, but I need Python v2.7. So I downloaded the source from python.org and tried to install it.

The first time I installed it, I ran:

```
cd Python2.7.4
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
su root
make install
```

This installs Python 2.7 to my system. It will create a link, "python", in `/usr/bin` linking to `python2.7` also in `/usr/bin`. So when I type `>python`, the system will start Python 2.7.4 for me just like when I type `>python2.7`.

But when I install this way:

```
cd Python2.7.4
./configure --prefix=/usr
make
su root
make altinstall
```

The link "python" in `/usr/bin` still exists and links to `python2.6` which is the default system version. Of course, I can remove it and create a new soft link linking to `python2.7`.

What is the difference between the command "make install" and "make altinstall", except for the link in `/usr/bin`?

Answer (score 183, accepted):

TLDR: `altinstall` skips creating the `python` link and the manual pages links, `install` will hide the system binaries and manual pages.

Let's take a look at the generated Makefile!

First, the install target:

```
install:         altinstall bininstall maninstall
```

It does everything `altinstall` does, along with `bininstall` and `maninstall`

Here's `bininstall`; it just creates the `python` and other symbolic links.

```
# Install the interpreter by creating a symlink chain:
#  $(PYTHON) -> python2 -> python$(VERSION))
# Also create equivalent chains for other installed files
bininstall:     altbininstall
        -if test -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(PYTHON) -o -h $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(PYTHON); \
        then rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/$(PYTHON); \
        else true; \
        fi
        (cd $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); $(LN) -s python2$(EXE) $(PYTHON))
        -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR)/python2$(EXE)
        (cd $(DESTDIR)$(BINDIR); $(LN) -s python$(VERSION)$(EXE) python2$(EXE))
        ... (More links created)
```

And here's `maninstall`, it just creates "unversioned" links to the Python manual pages.

```
# Install the unversioned manual pages
maninstall:     altmaninstall
        -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1/python2.1
        (cd $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1; $(LN) -s python$(VERSION).1 python2.1)
        -rm -f $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1/python.1
        (cd $(DESTDIR)$(MANDIR)/man1; $(LN) -s python2.1 python.1)
```

Comment: Ok, this answer is good and I understand. Thank you. I have a further question that is you just mentioned the "maininstall" is used to create the manual pages. What do you mean for "manual page"? The result of command "man python"?

Comment: Exactly, the `man` program looks for installed manual pages when it is run. To look at the 2.7 man pages after running `altinstall`, you'll need to use `man python2.7`

Comment: Specific guidance about using `make altinstall` over `make install` can be found in [Python's UNIX documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/using/unix.html?highlight=altinstall#building-python).

Comment: Awesome answer, but the TLDR should be at the top.

Comment: The TLDR si conventionally at the end.

Comment: I faced [this problem regarding lsb_release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44967202/pip-is-showing-error-lsb-release-a-returned-non-zero-exit-status-1). I fixed it by using altinstall - thank you very much!

Comment: I try to use virtualenv to create virutal env with python 3.6, if only altinstall, where to find the bin?

Comment: found in /usr/local/bin

Answer (score 21):

Simply: The `altinstall` target will make sure the default Python on your machine is not touched, or to avoid overwriting the *system* Python.

Comment: Unfortunately even `altinstall` will break `gdm3` in Kinetic Kudu