# Run Python Script in Python 2.7 And Not 2.6

Tags: python, shell, dreamhost, shebang

I am attempting to execute my script (on my Dreamhost server) with Python 2.7. Currently when I access my script it is run by Dreamhost's default version of Python 2.6.6. I have attempted to  make sure the script is run under Python 2.7 using this shebang `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7` BUT when I go to access my script it gives me a 404 error.

I have a feeling that my `.bash_profile` PATH variable is wrong. Is my `.bash_profile` file correct? It is the cause I why I cant run my script under Python 2.7?

Where I installed Python 2.7: `home/MY_USERNAME/Python`

`.bash_profile` File Contents:

```
# ~/.bash_profile: executed by bash(1) for login shells.

umask 002
PS1='[\h]$ '

PATH=/home/MY_USERNAME/python/bin:$HOME/bin:$PATH
export PATH

PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:$HOME/lib/python
export PYTHONPATH

MANPATH=$MANPATH:$HOME/man
export MANPATH
```

*Important Information: If I access my server via UNIX Shell and type: `python --version` it outputs `Python 2.7`. So under shell my `.bash_profile` is correct I guess?
*Important Information: I have tried the following shebangs but they all result in 404 errors: `#!/usr/bin/env python2.7` `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`
*Important Information: If I run my script with a regular shebang `#!/usr/bin/python`  the script executes fine but it runs under Python 2.6.6.

Comment: How is your web server set up to serve files from the location of the script?

Comment: @l0b0 not quite sure what you mean? If you mean do I have any special .htaccess code then no. Just regular wordpress and disallow directory listings inside .htaccess

Comment: If you want to serve any web pages, you have to configure your web server to do so. Attempting to reach any URL on that server which is not configured will typically result in a 404 return code, regardless of what your Python script looks like. In fact, it is *much* more likely that you'd get a *500* (generic server error) return code if the issue was really your shebang line.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the path of your Python installation, you can simply use that in the shebang line:

```
#!/home/MY_USERNAME/Python/bin/python
```

However, there are portable ways to do this, the best one of which is virtualenv. Once installed, you can simply create an environment for Python 2.7, then `. /path/to/virtualenv/bin/activate`, and presto - `/usr/bin/env python` points to Python 2.7.

Alternatively, if you have root access on the machine you could [`make altinstall`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16018463/difference-in-details-between-make-install-and-make-altinstall) from the Python tarball to install it along side with Python 2.6.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I tried that but its still gives me a 404 error. Note the path/url to the script I am using is correct.

Comment: I'll give virtualenv a go.