# Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing

Tags: python, compiler-errors, installation, python-3.4, failed-installation

I am using Ubuntu and have installed Python 2.7.5 and 3.4.0. In Python 2.7.5 I am able to successfully assign a variable `x = Value('i', 2)`, but not in 3.4.0. I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/context.py", line 132, in Value
      from .sharedctypes import Value
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/multiprocessing/sharedctypes.py", line 10, in <
module>
   import ctypes
   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
      from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I just updated to 3.3.2 through installing the source of 3.4.0. It installed in */usr/local/lib/python3.4*.

Did I update to Python 3.4 correctly?

One thing I noticed that Python 3.4 is installed in *usr/local/lib*, while Python 3.3.2 is still installed in *usr/lib*, so it was not overwritten.

Comment: It appears that something got fouled up during the "installing the source of 3.4.0". What does that mean exactly? Was that command working in 3.3.2?

Comment: I installed from the source code using the sudo make install command. Yes importing Value from multiprocessing worked in 3.3.2

Comment: `_ctypes` wasn't built because the `libffi-dev` dependency wasn't available. Consider using the [deadsnakes PPA](https://launchpad.net/~fkrull/+archive/ubuntu/deadsnakes) instead.

Comment: Installing libffi-dev and re-installing python3.4 fixed the problem for me

Answer (score 465):

Installing `libffi-dev` and re-installing python3.7 fixed the problem for me.

to cleanly build py 3.7  `libffi-dev`  is required or else later stuff will fail

**If using RHEL/Fedora:**

```
sudo yum install libffi-devel
```

or

```
sudo dnf install libffi-devel
```

**If using Debian/Ubuntu:**

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Comment: I have installed `libffi-dev` but I am still getting this error

Comment: If you are using linux，execute `ldconfig` to load the new `libffi.so`. The main purpose of `apt-get install libffi-dev` is to install an file called `libffi.so` which you can check it by `dpkg -L libffi-dev` @tushar_ecmc

Comment: Note that if you've compiled you're own Python distribution (eg through `pyenv install`), you'll need to re-compile the distribution after installing the package.

Comment: That worked for me on Python 3.9. I had 3.8 and it was working fine, then I installed 3.9 from source and pip install requirements was failing with the same error. After installing the suggested package and re built Python 3.9, it worked.

Comment: Installing libffi-dev and re-installing python3.8.7 did the trick for me! Thanks @steve-e

Comment: I needed to run `./confugure` with flag `--with-system-ffi` to make it use the built libffi.

Comment: How can I specify ffi path if its installed in a non default location?

Comment: Thanks, this also worked in windows bash/ubuntu when installing python3.8

Comment: Befoe you compile python3 , run this command first: sudo yum install gcc open-ssl-devel bzip2-devel libffi-devel -y

Comment: This definitely fixed the issue for me too (the Debian/Ubuntu option). Remember that _you have to recompile_ Python (version 3.9 in my case).

Comment: i'm trying to fix the error in mac, when i run `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/libffi/3_2_1 ` it gave me error ```clang: error: unsupported option '-print-multi-os-directory' clang: error: no input files```, anyone knows what's going on?

Comment: This worked for me in a different context: on Ubuntu 18 with a recently built/installed Python 3.11 tarball, and IntelliJ IDEA - running a project with the virtual environment worked fine, but debugging threw the error that led me here. Installing libffi-dev and re-installing Python (`make altinstall` in my case) solved the issue for me.

Comment: remember to resinstall python 3.7 after installing libffi-dev

Answer (score 167):

On a fresh Debian image, cloning https://github.com/python/cpython and running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-pip python-smbus
sudo apt-get install libncursesw5-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev openssl
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Now execute the `configure` file cloned above:

```
./configure
make # alternatively `make -j 4` will utilize 4 threads
sudo make altinstall
```

Got 3.7 installed and working for me.

## SLIGHT UPDATE

Looks like I said I would update this answer with some more explanation and two years later I don't have much to add.

- [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31002176/2223106) explains why certain libraries like `python-dev` might be necessary.
- [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16018816/2223106) explains why one might use the `altinstall` as opposed to `install` argument in the [make](http://www.sis.pitt.edu/mbsclass/tutorial/advanced/makefile/whatis.htm) command.

Aside from that I guess the choice would be to either read through the cpython codebase looking for `#include` directives that need to be met, but what I usually do is keep trying to install the package and just keep reading through the output installing the required packages until it succeeds.

Reminds me of the story of the [Engineer, the Manager and the Programmer whose car rolls down a hill](http://www.cs.uni.edu/~mccormic/humor.html).

Comment: Fantastic. Now, can you tell me how you got the list above? By trial and error? :-O

Comment: Honestly, @Veky I dida a web search for the error, "ImportError: No module named '_ctypes'" and dug around, probably tried a few things before it worked. Will update answer to clarify with my scant understanding of APT, Python, make, etc.

Comment: It should be `python3-dev` instead of `python-dev`. `python-dev` seems for `python2`.

Comment: Why would you clone a source code repo, and then use `sudo apt-get`? That just doesn't make any sense. `sudo apt-get` handles the downloading of already compiled code, so why do you download the code and then not use it?

Comment: @Ryan that's a great point. I don't remember how I came to this approach. Pretty sure I mostly found it somewhere. Looking back, I'm also not seeing any actual use of the cloned repository. Can you confirm that it will work without cloning the repo? If so, we should probably remove that line, or at least just change it to referencing the github repo in case someone wants to look at it.

Comment: @MikeiLL I realized all the `sudo` statements are installing pre-requisites in order to go build the source code you downloaded. the `./configure` and `make` stuff requires those things to be installed.

Comment: Additional dependencies for optional libraries; `liblzma-dev` `uuid-dev` `libreadline-dev` (for Python 3.7 at on Debian 9 least)

Comment: after installing libffi-devel it still didn't worked for me. It turned out i need to uninstall python first (as it was installed prior libffi-devel installation) and then reinstall it (python) again - from then on everything\ worked as expected.

Comment: I was building python 3.8 for mint from source and kept having this problem. After installing this list though i rebuilt python and i no longer had the ctypes error

Answer (score 164):

If you use pyenv and get error "No module named '_ctypes'" (like i am) on Debian/Raspbian/Ubuntu you need to run this commands:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
pyenv uninstall 3.7.6
pyenv install 3.7.6
```

Put your version of python instead of 3.7.6

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Can you provide more information? References etc
and have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the highest voted had the full list I likely needed, but this reminded me to reinstall via `pyenv` in order to actually get things working. Using pyenv is way easier than grabbing the source code and doing all the `make` stuff for sure.

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu. Simple and effective.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. For full list of prerequisite for pyenv visit https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems#prerequisites

Comment: You do not need to uninstall Python first. Just installing it over again will recompile Python binary and that's what's needed.

Comment: I tried each one of the answers above but with no success. Only your answer worked. Thanks

Comment: Yup, reinstalling python is necessary.

Comment: Solved it on CentOS as well! :+1:

Answer (score 31):

Detailed steps to install Python 3.7 in CentOS or any redhat linux machine:

1. Download Python from https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.0/Python-3.7.0.tar.xz
2. Extract the content in new folder
3. Open Terminal in the same directory
4. Run below code step by step :

> ```
> sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ 
> sudo yum -y install zlib zlib-devel
> sudo yum -y install libffi-devel 
> ./configure
> make
> make install
> ```

Comment: this does not work anymore with CentOS. `No package libffi-devel is available`

Comment: @con If your CentOS is old (which means CentOS 6 as of writing), I think the repos have disappeared? You can get packages from vault.centos.org/6.8/os/x86_64/Packages (adjust for your version and platform). I got libffi-devel from there.

Comment: This link helped me solve the same issue. (running CentOs7) http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/Packages/libffi-devel-3.0.13-19.el7.x86_64.rpm

Answer (score 21):

Thought I'd add the Centos installs:

```
sudo yum -y install gcc gcc-c++ 
sudo yum -y install zlib zlib-devel
sudo yum -y install libffi-devel
```

Check python version:

`python3 -V`

Create virtualenv:

`virtualenv -p python3 venv`

Comment: this was flagged as low quality, and i'm looking at it in the review queue.  it really doesn't work as a stand-alone answer.  i'm going to recommend deletion, but maybe you can improve it by expanding it?

Answer (score 21):

On my Ubuntu 18.04 machine, I had the common problem of python not finding `_ctypes` with the pyenv installed python.

In my case `libffi-dev` was already installed. Installing `cpython` from source, as suggested by **@MikeiLL**, didn't help either.

Turned out to be an homebrew issue.

[ajkerrigans suggested solution on pyenvs github issues](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/2159#issuecomment-983960026-permalink) solved this problem for me.

**Solution summary:** Tell pyenv to build Python using the Homebrew-managed GCC, with a command like:

```
CC="$(brew --prefix gcc)/bin/gcc-11" \
pyenv install --verbose 3.10.0
```

This assumes that any build dependencies have also been installed via Homebrew as specified in the [pyenv wiki](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki#suggested-build-environment). As of this writing, that looks like this for Homebrew on Linux:

```
brew install bzip2 libffi libxml2 libxmlsec1 openssl readline sqlite xz zlib
```

Comment: Please quote or summerize the solution you are referring to here, in your answer.

Comment: please quote or summerize the answer you are referring to here so that your answer is more clear!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30704585)

Comment: Thanks for linking this here @n14s. Since you did me the favor of linking here, I've edited your answer to include a solution summary. Feel free to keep/modify/trash any of those changes of course. Cheers :).

Comment: I have the LinuxBrew and have this issue too. Force to use Homebrew GCC work for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me on Debian (in WSL)

Comment: This worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04, pyenv, python 3.8.13, & brew

Answer (score 17):

This **solved** the same error for me on **Debian**:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

and compile again

Reference: [issue31652](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652)

Answer (score 15):

None of the solution worked. You have to recompile your python again; once all the required packages were completely installed.

Follow this:

1. Install required packages
2. Run `./configure --enable-optimizations`

https://gist.github.com/jerblack/798718c1910ccdd4ede92481229043be

Comment: Great answer actually. 
Everyone mentions that you need libffi-devel and that it would solve it, problem is that  you also need to recompile python. 

I alsmot gave up on libffi.

Comment: Link no longer works. Use https://web.archive.org/web/20230314215703/https://gist.github.com/jerblack/798718c1910ccdd4ede92481229043be instead.

Comment: where do you run `./configure`?

Answer (score 13):

I run into this error when I tried to install **Python 3.7.3** in **Ubuntu 18.04** with next command: `$ pyenv install 3.7.3`.
Installation succeeded after running `$ sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` (as suggested [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652)).
The issue was solved [there](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1183).

Answer (score 10):

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41310760/13093413) answer, just copy-paste into the terminal.

First run:
`sudo apt-get -y update`

then:

```
sudo apt-get -y upgrade
sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
sudo apt-get -y install build-essential python-dev python-setuptools python-pip python-smbus
sudo apt-get -y install libncursesw5-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev
sudo apt-get -y install zlib1g-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev
sudo apt-get -y install libssl-dev openssl
sudo apt-get -y install libffi-dev
```

PS: You can just copy-paste the whole chunk into the terminal in one go.

Answer (score 5):

In my case what was causing all sorts of Python installation issues including the one having to do with `_ctypes` and `libffi` was [Homebrew on Linux / Linuxbrew](https://docs.brew.sh/Homebrew-on-Linux). `pyenv` was happy again once `brew` was no longer in the `$PATH`.

Comment: @n14s solution by forcing pyenv to use HomeBrew managed GCC work for me. Maybe a solution for those who want to keep Homebrew and pyenv in the same time.

Answer (score 4):

Refer to [this thread](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2018-December/738568.html) or [this thread](https://bugs.python.org/issue34823), for customized installation of libffi, it is difficult for Python3.7 to find the library location of libffi. An alternative method is to set the `CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS` variable in the Makefile, for example `CONFIGURE_LDFLAGS="-L/path/to/libffi-3.2.1/lib64"`.

Comment: The link is broken. I attempted to make the modification in the Makefile as you show here but it didn't work. _ctypes is still not building.

Answer (score 3):

My solution:
Installing libffi-dev with apt-get didn't help.
But this helped: Installing libffi from source and then installing Python 3.8 from source.

My configuration:
Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Python 3.8.2

Step by step:

I got the error message "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'" when starting the debugger from Visual Studio Code, and when running `python3 -c "import sklearn; sklearn.show_versions()"`.

- download libffi v3.3 from https://github.com/libffi/libffi/releases
- install libtool: `sudo apt-get install libtool`
  The file README.md from libffi mentions that autoconf and automake are also necessary. They were already installed on my system.
- configure libffi without docs:

`./configure --disable-docs`

`make check`

`sudo make install`

- download python 3.8 from https://www.python.org/downloads/
- `./configure`
- `make`
- `make test`
- `make install`

After that my python installation could find _ctypes.

Comment: For me it fails with error `generate posix-vars failed`. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

CentOS without root

1. Install libffi-3.2 (Do NOT use libffi-3.3)

   wget ftp://sourceware.org/pub/libffi/libffi-3.2.tar.gz
   tar -xzf libffi-3.2.tar.gz
   cd libffi-3.2/
   ./configure --prefix=$YOUR_LIBFFI_DIR
   make && make install
2. Install Python3

   ./configure --prefix=$YOUR_PATH/python/3.7.10 LDFLAGS=-L${YOUR_LIBFFI_DIR}/lib64 PKG_CONFIG_PATH=${YOUR_LIBFFI_DIR}/lib/pkgconfig --enable-shared

   make && make install

Thanks for [JohnWSteill](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1183)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem. None of the above solutions worked for me. The key challenge was that I didn't have the root access. So, I first download the source of libffi. Then I compiled it with usual commands:

```
./configure --prefix=desired_installation_path_to_libffi
make
```

Then I recompiled python using

```
./configure --prefix=/home/user123/Softwares/Python/installation3/  LDFLAGS='-L/home/user123/Softwares/library/libffi/installation/lib64'
make 
make install
```

In my case, 'home/user123/Softwares/library/libffi/installation/lib64' is path to LIBFFI installation directory where libffi.so is located. And, /home/user123/Softwares/Python/installation3/ is path to Python installation directory. Modify them as per your case.

Answer (score 1):

If your issue is with the VSCODE DEBUGGER, check your currently selected python interpreter. I had both python3.10.9 and python3.10.6 installed; however, the former was probably missing some dependencies so I switched to the latter(my OS default interpreter) which solved the issue.

To change your python interpreter in VSCODE:

1. Hold ctrl+shift+P
2. Search `Python:Select Interpreter` and try your OS default version(The version you get when you run `python3 --version`
3. If the issue is still not resolved, run `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using [Miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html), the necessary external libraries and _ctypes are installed by default. It does take more space and may require using a moderately older version of Python (e.g. 3.7.6 instead of 3.8.2 as of this writing).

Answer (score 0):

**How to install Python from source without libffi in `/usr/local`?**

1. Download libffi from github and install to `/path/to/local`
2. Download python source code and compile with the following configuration:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/path/to/local/lib/pkgconfig
./configure --prefix=/path/to/python \
    LDFLAGS='-L/path/to/local/lib -Wl,-R/path/to/local/lib' \
    --enable-optimizations
make
make install
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using **MAC M1** and I had this *error*:

```
... __boot__.py", line 30, in <module> import ctypes
and something was said about the file libffi.8.dylib
```

I *downloaded* this thing on **Anaconda** and now everything works:

```
https://anaconda.org/wakari/libffi
```

I inform you, since much of the above is either not for **MAC** or outdated, my **Python** is on *Anaconda* **version 3.10.4**

*Application file created with py2app works now!!*

Answer (score 0):

Similar case:

- **Environment**: Windows 11, Python 3.11
- **Issue**: use IDA to open binary file, error:

  ```bash
  E:\DevTools\iOSReverse\IDA\IDA7.5\IDAPro\loaders\uimage.py: No module named '_ctypes'
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "E:\DevTools\iOSReverse\IDA\IDA7.5\IDAPro\python\3\ida_idaapi.py", line 616, in IDAPython_ExecScript
  exec(code, g)
  File "E:/DevTools/iOSReverse/IDA/IDA7.5/IDAPro/loaders/uimage.py", line 79, in <module>
  import ctypes
  File "E:\DevInstall\Python311\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
  from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
  ```
- **Solution**: Add system environment variable:

  - `PYTHONPATH` = `E:\DevInstall\Python311\Lib;E:\DevInstall\Python311\DLLs;E:\DevInstall\Python311\tcl;`
  - `PYTHONHOME`=`E:\DevInstall\Python311`
- **Refer**: [ImportError : No module named '_ctypes'](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet/issues/932)

  - > Ctypes is included in the standard library
  - > _ctypes.pyd is in PYTHONHOME/DLLs. You should include the directory in your PYTHONPATH environment variable

Answer (score 0):

This is relevant to, and solves [a problem](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/15289) that popped up with [vscode-jupyter](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter).

To use Jupyter in VSCode, you need to install `libffi-devel` first.

So, if you're using `pyenv` you need to install `libffi-devel`, uninstall the `pyenv` versions you need to use, then reinstall them:

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
pyenv uninstall <Python version>
pyenv install <Python version>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to load the missing php3 (Python3) modules from the package manager.
If you have Ubuntu I recommend the `Synaptic Package Manager`:

```
sudo apt-get install synaptic
```

There you can simply search for the missing modules. search for ctypes and install all the packages. Then go to your Python dir and do

```
./configure
make install.
```

This should solve your problem.

Answer (score -3):

If you are doing something nobody here will listen you about because "you're doing it the wrong way", but you have to do it "the wrong way" for reasons too asinine to explain and also beyond your ability to control, you can try this:

Get libffi and install it into your user install area the usual way.

```
git clone https://github.com/libffi/libffi.git
cd libffi
./configure --prefix=path/to/your/install/root
make
make install
```

Then go back to your Python 3 source and find this part of the code in setup.py at the top level of the python source directory

```py
        ffi_inc = [sysconfig.get_config_var("LIBFFI_INCLUDEDIR")]
        if not ffi_inc or ffi_inc[0] == '':
            ffi_inc = find_file('ffi.h', [], inc_dirs)
        if ffi_inc is not None:
            ffi_h = ffi_inc[0] + '/ffi.h'
            if not os.path.exists(ffi_h):
                ffi_inc = None
                print('Header file {} does not exist'.format(ffi_h))
        ffi_lib = None
        if ffi_inc is not None:
            for lib_name in ('ffi', 'ffi_pic'):
                if (self.compiler.find_library_file(lib_dirs, lib_name)):
                    ffi_lib = lib_name
                    break

        ffi_lib="ffi"  # --- AND INSERT THIS LINE HERE THAT DOES NOT APPEAR ---
        if ffi_inc and ffi_lib:
            ext.include_dirs.extend(ffi_inc)
            ext.libraries.append(ffi_lib)
            self.use_system_libffi = True
```

and add the line I have marked above with the comment. Why it is necessary, and why there is no way to get configure to respect '--without-system-ffi` on Linux platforms, perhaps I will find out why that is "unsupported" in the next couple of hours, but everything has worked ever since. Otherwise, best of luck... YMMV.

WHAT IT DOES: just overrides the logic there and causes the compiler linking command to add "-lffi" which is all that it really needs. If you have the library user-installed, it is probably detecting the headers fine as long as your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` includes `path/to/your/install/root/lib/pkgconfig`.

Comment: Shameful copy paste from Github issue.

Comment: Mind sharing a link to that github issue @MurtazaHaji? The code above is directly from the source except the inserted line, so of course that is going to match github. The rest is my smack talk kind of writing which I can guarantee you is original and unlikely to how another would phrase the same thing, so if that content appears elsewhere, it was cut and paste from here. Curious as to the date of that github issue - and also whether they fixed it.