# Upgrade Python 3.4.3 to Python 3.6.1 in Ubuntu 15.04(64 bit)

Tags: python, linux, python-2.7, python-3.x, ubuntu-15.04

I have `Python 2.7.9` and `Python 3.4.3` installed in a Ubuntu 15.04 machine. Now I want to upgrade `Python 3.4.3` to `Python 3.6.1` without affecting the packages which are depended on `Python 3.x.x`. I have found that Python versions are released as separate package. So, my questions are:

- Can I actually upgrade `Python 3.4.3` to `Python 3.6.1`?
- If the answer is no, can I uninstall `Python 3.4.3` and install `Python 3.6.1` without affecting the installed packages?
- If the second answer is no, then what will happen if I install `Python 3.6.1` using `sudo apt-get install python 3.6.1`? Can I use `Python 3.6.1` without affecting other versions using `Python3.6` command in terminal and in virtual environments?

### Update

I have installed Python 3.6 from -> https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758621/3129414

Answer (score 12):

1. Open to terminal window and enter `$ python`. This will open python interpretor with v2.7.
2. If your have installed python v3.4 in your system. Then run `$ python3`, this will open the python interpretor with v3.4.
3. Yes, python v3.6 can be installed without affecting other versions with the following below steps :

   a) `$ wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.3/Python-3.6.3.tgz`

   b) `$ tar xvf Python-3.6.3.tgz`

   c) `$ cd Python-3.6.3`

   d) `$ ./configure --enable-optimizations`

   e) `$ make -j8`

   f) `$ sudo make altinstall`

Then, to run python with v3.6 , run `$ python3.6`

Comment: Could you also include the steps to uninstall the same? It would be extremely helpful.