# "ssl module in Python is not available"

Tags: python, pip

still advancing in my tutorial to learn python, I was told to do

```
sudo -H pip install requests
```

I get the following :

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting requests
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for requests
```

would someone know what I need to do to fix that once for all ?

thanks so much in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SSL module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Answer (score 10):

I use Linux distros and face the problem since the new installation of Python 3.6.
I tried a couple of solution and finally solved the problem. The steps I followed are as below.

On Debian like distros

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall libreadline-gplv2-dev ibncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev
```

Change the directory to the Python3.6 location

```
cd /path/to/Python3.6/Module/
```

In the module directory, open the `Setup` file with your preferred text editor

```
vi Setup
```

Search for `SSL` and uncomment the related lines.

```
ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto
```

Save the file and on the root folder of your Python package, run the following command.

```
make
sudo make install
```

And finally, run the `pip3` to install your required module(s).

Comment: Working solution, but here are 2 corrections: 
1. cd /path/to/Python3.6/Module/ = .../Modules/
2. ibncursesw5-dev = libncursesw5-dev

Comment: Shouldn't I also uncomment the `SSL=/usr/local/ssl` line in the Setup file?

Comment: I think you mean `libncursesw5-dev` instead of `ibncursesw5-dev`.

Comment: This requires the OpenSSL _development_ package, which (on Ubuntu) is called `libssl-dev`. Be sure you have this installed too.

Answer (score 4):

Running `./configure` with `--enable-optimizations` did the trick.

Here are the steps that worked for me on a Ubuntu 16.04 LTS box-

1. The lines related to `ssl` in the `Modules/Setup*` files are commented
2. cd to the directory where you have the Python tar extracted

   `cd /../../../Python-3.7.4/`
3. Run configure with optimizations enabled

   `./configure --enable-optimizations`
4. Run make and then make install

   `make`

   `make install`

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this problem running pip on Powershell on Windows, using the Anaconda distribution. I was running it inside VSCode, but I don't think it makes much difference.

A quick turnaround for me was installing what I needed using the Anaconda prompt, which works fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
I encountered the problem when installing 3.8.11. I tried the above posts but they didn't work.

This is how I finally made it compile:

1) Install openssl 1.1.1g;
2) untar the tarball;
3) enter the source directory;
4) run ./config --prefix=/usr/local/openssl_1.1 --openssldir=/usr/local/openssl_1.1
to install to /usr/local/openssl_1.1.

make & make install.

You can customize the directory.
5)Download python 3.8 source tarball;
6)untar the tarball. Enter the source/Modules;
7) edit the file Setup;
8) find the lines:

SSL=/usr/local/ssl

ssl _ssl.c \
    -DUSE_SSL -I$(SSL)/include -I$(SSL)/include/openssl \
    -L$(SSL)/lib -lssl -lcrypto

change SSL=/usr/local/ssl to SSL=/usr/local/openssl_1.1

9) Switch to the source directory. run

./configure --prefix=/usr/local/python3.8 --with-openssl=/usr/local/openssl_1.1

10) export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/openssl_1.1/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH

11) make & make install. If you need sudo, also export LD_LIBRARY_PATH in sudo
```

Answer (score 0):

This command worked very well for me.

```
cd Python-3.6.2
./configure --with-ssl
make
sudo make install
```

Comment: configure: WARNING: unrecognized options: --with-ssl

Answer (score -1):

I encountered the same problem in Windows 10.

What I did was:

**Step 1:** go to https://pypi.python.org/simple/requests and download the latest version (e.g., requests-2.21.0.tar.gz).

**Step 2:** unzip the downloaded file into a folder (e.g., c:\temp\requests-2.21.0). You can use 7zip for that purpose.

**Step 3:** pip install c:\temp\requests-2.21.0

Note: pip can also install a local folder.

It worked for me.