# Python SSL module is not available on mac?

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, opencv, pip

Ok, I needed opencv 4 installed on my mac, so I followed https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/08/17/install-opencv-4-on-macos/ and got opencv installed and the virtual environment `cv` set up.

I'm running Python 3.7.3. Since setting this up, I am unable to install any packages due to SSL problems. Trying `pip install spell` after `workon cv` -

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/spell/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/spell/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement spell (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for spell
```

I've tried brew uninstalling `openssl` and reinstalling, as well as other SO solutions like ["ssl module in Python is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49094768/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available) however im on macos not linux.

How can I install pip packages?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50508580/7976758

Comment: @phd I tried that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have both Python2.7 and Python3 on your system.
Try

```
pip --version
```

If the result is like:

```
pip 19.3.1 from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip (python 2.7)
```

your pip defaults to Python2

So just try with

```
pip3 install spell
```