# "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available"

Tags: python, download, openssl, pip, anaconda

I have the anaconda package and run Spyder. Here is my system information:

```
anaconda                  2018.12                  py37_0

Python                    3.7.1

pip                       18.1

Dell Inspiron 13 7000 64-bit
```

I am unable to install anything with pip from the command prompt. I get the following when trying to install numpy for instance (which I already have through anaconda):

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Requirement already satisfied: numpy in c:\users\uday rallabhandi\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (1.15.4)

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Please help me understand why this is happening.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3

Comment: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/issues/2208

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here was my process to correct the error, on Windows 10 with Anaconda:

1. Added the following paths to my environment variables:

- /AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3
- /AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Scripts
- /AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Library
- /AppData/Local/Continuum/Anaconda3/Library/Bin

At this stage, the error message was still there.

2. From Anaconda Prompt, I installed the latest version of pip:

   ```bash
   python -m pip install --upgrade pip
   ```

This appeared to correct the DLL conflict.

Comment: Worked for me on Win10. Why is /Library not added to PATH by anaconda3 by default?!

Comment: This solution was the only one that works for me thank you very much. Win 10 pro

Comment: that solution works. that file `anaconda3\Library\bin\libssl-1_1-x64.dll` should be in `$PATH`

Comment: Worked for me as well but I didn't have to upgrade pip (Windows 10). @DmitryAvtonomov I think Anaconda installer now gives you the option whether to add to path or not. By defualt the option is not selected and it's "not recommended"

Comment: If the environment is within QGIS and Anaconda is not in the equation at all, is there an alternative?  None of these solutions work for me.

Answer (score 19):

I had exactly the same problem. My computer is exactly the same and the versions of Python and pip are also the same.

It's a dll conflict with libeay32.dll.

I can solve this problem by adding dir path of python which has libeay32.dll (in my case C:\Users\Gabriel\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1a-he774522_0\Library\bin) in system environment as topmost position.

Comment: i have: .../pkgs/openssl-1.1.1a-he774522_0, but no libeay32.dll. where else can i find it for win 8.1?

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue when I created a new environment in anaconda, activated it and tried to install a library with pip. What was missing was:

```
conda install pip
```

then everything worked for me.

Comment: Not the same situation as I already had a currently operational pip, but something did get mucked up by me. Either way, this also served to solve my issue before taking the nuclear approach! thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try your install/update with *pip3* instead of *pip*.

Answer (score 7):

I do not have libeay32.dll in bin folder either, but after adding `C:\Users\<user name>\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1a-he774522_0\Library\bin` to the top of path, it is working. This is on Windows 10 64-bit.

Answer (score 6):

Activate your base conda environment:

`conda activate base`

Answer (score 4):

Adding **"<Path to miniconda or anaconda>\Library\bin"** folder to PATH solved this problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

Add `<Path to miniconda or anaconda>\Library\bin` folder to `PATH`
or
`cd <Path to miniconda or anaconda>\Library\bin>`

Answer (score 0):

Activating the base and then activated my Django environment.

(Django_env) (base) C:\virtual_environment\Django_env> , which actually worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

just a note how to find wich library is missing

```
$ python -m ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ssl.py", line 99, in <module>
    import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ImportError: libssl.so.1.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Comment: Everyone above is talking about Windows, but these are Linux paths. Also, I tried this on my Windows machine - `python -m ssl` runs without error, but I still can't install anything using pip.