# confirming of ssl module in python 3.7 ,ssl module not available

Tags: python-3.x, pip, ssl-certificate

i tried many things that are posted for different versions but not able to overcome this problem. Is there anything to be replaced in script location ? or add any code ?

```
C:\Users\HARSHA>pip install speechrecognition
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting speechrecognition
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/speechrecognition/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/speechrecognition/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement speechrecognition (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for speechrecognition
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

[image: this is the error i am geting]

Answer (score -1):

I believe it's the same error.

["pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394764/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-i)

The solution was:

*"I can solve this problem by adding dir path of python which has libeay32.dll (in my case C:\Users\Gabriel\Anaconda3\pkgs\openssl-1.1.1a-he774522_0\Library\bin) in system environment as topmost position."*

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54531318/2747958.

Comment: This should be a comment, not an answer. If it is a duplicate question, [vote to close](//stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions) as such and/or leave a comment once you [earn](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/146472) enough [reputation](//stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation). If not, *tailor the answer to this specific question*.