# Problems on installing pip (command prompt)

Tags: python, pip, command-prompt

I am new to Python and need to download some modules for a project that I am doing, however, I am getting this error whenever I try to download pip. Would this error be as a result of a firewall? If so, is there any way I can get around to installing pip?

```
U:\>Py get-pip.py
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however 
the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting pip
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS 
URL 
because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS 
URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS 
URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS 
URL 
 because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
 WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, 
 status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to 
HTTPS 
  URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem 
 confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', 
 port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by 
 SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not 
 available.")) - skipping
 ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from 
 versions: none)
 ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
 WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however 
 the 
ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem 
confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', 
port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by 
SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not 
available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: if you have python installed you already have pip, just use ` python -m pip install <my_library>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394764/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-i/54394791

Comment: Just use the [python installer for windows](https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.7.4/python-3.7.4.exe). It will install pip automatically and add both `python` and `pip` to $PATH.

Comment: @CodeIt Oh if that is the case then I may already have it since that is where I downloaded it from yesterday. However, whenever I open Python 3.7 and type in 'pip install networkx' it would just tell me 'invalid synatx'

Comment: @ElizabethDC You are opening python interpreter. `pip` cannot be used inside the interpreter. Just open CMD and type `pip --version` to see if it is already installed.

Comment: @ElizabethDC See if you have pip installed.

Comment: @CodeIt I have just input this on command prompt just now and it said that 'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: @CodeIt I have had this same problem when I just type in Python, and it didn't work, but when I typed in py, it confirmed it

Comment: @ElizabethDC Usually when you install using the installer. It will ask you whether to add python to path. If you have not checked that box, it will not add python to $PATH. If you not sure what to do to solve this, you can try re-installing python using the installer. This time make sure you are checking the option to add python to $PATH.

Comment: @CodeIt Thank you I am currently now uninstalling Python to reinstall again. I will give this a go and will update you on what happens.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install [OpenSSL](https://slproweb.com/download/Win64OpenSSL-1_1_1c.exe), if your OS is Windows.

`get-pip.py` tries to extract the SSL certificates from requests in order to verify the pypi.org as a trusted host. Chances are your `python --version` installation was not built with SSL support, due to the unavailability of openSSL binaries within your OS.
On the second thought, make sure your python binaries and lib are added into your system PATH variable.

Once OpenSSL installed run `py get-pip.py`.

In order to make sure pip is installed, run `pip --version` in your command prompt.

Further, installing other modules using pip behind a corporate firewall can be done [using a proxy](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server) with your `pip install` commands.

```
pip install --proxy http://user:password@proxyserver:port <module-name>
```

Comment: Do I just install OpenSSL and would it then allow me to install pip? Would I need to do anything else after downloading openssl?

Comment: @ElizabethDC After installing OpenSSL, you need to run `Py get-pip.py` to install `pip`.

Comment: @CodeIt Would it also let me download other modules as well? I have tried using anaconda prompt to get modules or even just from the anaconda environment but the firewall at my workplace would not let me do so. I have just been trying to figure out how I could go about downloading modules without tinkering about things too much

Comment: In order to get through the firewall while installing other modules. You can use proxy as specified [here](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#using-a-proxy-server).

Also you should Command Prompt instead of Anaconda Prompt in order to install pip. For some reasons Anaconda Prompt fails to verify the SSL Certificate as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49943410/pip-ssl-error-on-windows)

Answer (score -1):

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get-pip.py
python get-pip.py
```

For this kind of problems is better to use github, copy and paste google and check for github issues.

Comment: I typed this into Python and it said install was an invalid syntax?

Comment: OP is trying to install `pip`.

Comment: Updated it, please check it

Comment: Op has already downloaded the `get-pip.py` file. OP is having problem installing it`U:\>Py get-pip.py`