# Getting error during attempts to install numpy - python 3

Tags: python, windows, numpy

I just installed PyCharm on my computer and I want to download `numpy` on WIN7.
I put `pip install numpy` in PaCharm's terminal, but got this error:

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting numpy
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not availabl
e.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not availabl
e.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not availabl
e.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not availabl
e.")': /simple/numpy/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not availabl
e.")': /simple/numpy/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
 /simple/numpy/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /si
mple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I found advice to write: 
`pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools`
but when I put this, I got this:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
ERROR: To modify pip, please run the following command:
C:\Users\Admin\PycharmProjects\lab05\venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install --trusted-host pypi.org --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org pip setuptools
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /si
mple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I've read that I need to find python.exe in Scripts, so I've found it and typed this line to the terminal, but I got this:

[image]

What should I do?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["SSL module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: @Mr.S its for linux

Answer (score 0):

This error might be caused because openssl is missing. Just reinstalling openssl (or installing it for the first time) might fix the problem. The following user seems to have fixed a similar problem in windows. https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932141/8292612