# installing numpy Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, numpy, pip

I have this problem when i install numpy on Raspberry Pi ( Python 3.6.6 without anaconda):

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop$ sudo pip3 install numpy
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting numpy
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/numpy/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available. - skipping
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for numpy
```

What went wrong and how can I fix it?

Comment: maybe you need to first install OpenSSL? ```sudo apt-get install openssl
```

Comment: pi@raspberrypi:~/Desktop$ sudo apt-get install openssl
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be upgraded:
  openssl
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 373 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/712 kB of archives.
After this operation, 72.7 kB of additional disk space will be used.

Comment: *** Error in `/usr/bin/python3': free(): invalid pointer: 0x003e2bd0 ***
Aborted
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script /usr/bin/apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10

Comment: hm, what distribution have you installed? It is hard to diagnoze anything with so little information, we just know now, that numpy cannot be installed via SSL and that openSSL cannot be installed either...

Comment: what distribution exactly?

Comment: I am sorry, I meant the OS, like Ubuntu... Which version, how, is WiFi properly configured, ... :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
I work on Raspberry Pi 3 B+ (debian), and an ethernet network

Comment: Try to follow these instructions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3

Answer (score 0):

hmm maybe try to run the command `sudo apt install python3-openssl` then run the command you were trying before and see if you still have the same issue

If there is still an error then try to install all dependencies for python with `sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libssl-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev`

Hope this works :)