# Problems with installing packages in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a problem with installing Packages in PyCharm. I tried to install SpeechRecognition and other packages and i always got something like this:

```
Collecting SpeechRecognition
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/speechrecognition/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/speechrecognition/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/speechrecognition/
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement SpeechRecognition (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for SpeechRecognition
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

What can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: Are you using conda as a project interpreter? Could you please try our latest build https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/nextversion/? We've done many conda-related improvements.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ssl module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Answer (score 2):

For Windows 10 if you want use pip in normal cmd, not only in Anaconda prompt. you need add 3 environment paths. like these: D:\Anaconda3; D:\Anaconda3\Scripts; D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin

most people only add D:\Anaconda3\Scripts;

Stolen from [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Comment: Thank you it worked! I have a virtual environment which also doesn't work but I have to add it to PATH too

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (I am on a Mac environment).
By updating openssl it solved the problem !!

```
brew upgrade openssl
```

It also updated the python version that I had to 3.8 because dependencies so I had to recreate the interpreter in Pycharm by it worked.