# How to declare the Python 3.7 in my path directory in Windows 10 after installation of Anaconda3?

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed Anaconda3 (2019) which comes with Python 3.7.

However, when I run from cmd python I am informed that I run Python 3.6.5:

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.| (default, Mar 29 2018, 13:32:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>
```

I have declared Anaconda3 in my Path variable:

[image]

The python.exe is contained in a directory that I can not declare in my Path:

[image]

[image]

---

The directories under Anaconda3 are the following:

[image]

There is no bins subdirectory here.

But there is a python.exe file:

[image]

I have declared its path in the Path variable:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anaconda3, the path to python is:
`/anaconda3/bin/python` instead of `/anaconda3/pkgs/...` (as you did). Try the former one.

Also, make sure that you **restart** your terminal after changing your PATH.

Note: you can always use `which python` in your terminal to check your python location.

Comment: `(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>python
Python 3.6.5 |Anaconda, Inc.|` indicates that you are already using anaconda python. Did you make sure that you installed the correct version of anaconda?

Comment: Please check this new post of mine: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58367721/c-windows-system32conda-update-all-conda-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or

Comment: In addtion to `C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3`, try PATH 

`C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3\Scripts
C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3\Library\bin`. Not sure if this helps... : )

Comment: You were right in that there was an installation of Anaconda under Visual Studio which I was not aware of.  Moreover, there was a python installation under Microsoft ML Server.  These have been cleared and now when I start python from cmd it is python 3.7.  However now I can not launch Jupyter Notebook and conda -- both are not recognized.

Comment: I added C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\Scripts to my path.  Now I am getting error messages when trying to launch jupyter notebook and run conda update all.

Comment: You can see at this related post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368256/when-running-jupyter-notebook-command-error-message-importerror-dll-load-fail

Comment: Moreover, when I try the command: conda update all I get the error message:  TypeError: LoadLibrary() argument 1 must be str, not None

Comment: 1) Did you try what I stated above: add PATH `C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3`, `C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3\Scripts` and `C:\Users\yourusername\Anaconda3\Library\bin`. 2) Or: conda activate `your_env` before jupyter notebook, To see all you conda envs, type `conda info --envs`. Further reference: https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/4332

Comment: The problems were resolved.  Now I have a new problem.  I can not run pip.  I am geting the error message: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: I added the paths to the Path variable and activated the conda.  Also installed Anaconda.   But now I have a serious problem with pip.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368600/pip-install-does-not-work-pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls

Comment: would u kindly give me an upvote since we have discussed for a while : D. I am also looking into your issues.

Comment: Certainly Vyvyen, I just did it.  Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: 1) try re-install/upgarde your pip. 2) did you activate conda env? e.g. `conda activate base`. 3) further related problems: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758621/10243559 Good luck!

Comment: Yes it was resolved by conda activate base once more.