# pip install ... does not work: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: python, windows, pip, anaconda

I installed Anaconda3 (2019), Python 3.7, Windows 10 yesterday and now I can not run `pip install <package>`.

When I run pip install , I get the following message:  `pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.`

When I tried to install ssl module I am getting the same error message:

```
D:\>pip install D:\ssl-1.16.tar.gz
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Processing d:\ssl-1.16.tar.gz
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\Alienware\Anaconda3\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-fdke_oc7\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\Alienware\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-req-build-fdke_oc7\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base pip-egg-info
         cwd: C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fdke_oc7\
    Complete output (6 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\Alienware\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build-fdke_oc7\setup.py", line 33
        print 'looking for', f
                          ^
    SyntaxError: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print('looking for', f)?
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

It seems that pip does not work because the module ssl is not installed but how to install module ssl when pip is not working?

Answer (score 0):

Resolved after running:

```
conda activate base
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your package is not suitable for python3, the syntax it writes is the syntax of python2. You need an ssl installation package for python3

Comment: Where I will find it?  There seem to be only one ssl package installed by pip install ssl.

Comment: I checked the documentation and found that python3 already comes with the ssl module, you don't need to install it. You can import it directly using import ssl