# "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available." Despite running as trusted host

Tags: python

I know there's several other people asking the same thing but neither works for me.
I'm on MacOS and I'm getting "pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available."
The solution everywhere is to run it as a trusted package:

```
pip install --trusted-host pypi.org \
          --trusted-host files.pythonhosted.org \
          requests
```

I am getting the same error though. Is it possible to ignore ssl?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try to upgrade pip library using the below command.

```
sudo pip install --upgrade
```

Then after use below command to install SSL module of python3.x

```
sudo pip install ssl
```

If the error still persists then try the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59279854/6505847)

Comment: Thanks and apologies for the late reply, I'm not in here too often. I managed to get it to work somehow, don't remember how