# .pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. (Windows 10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, pip, quandl

I am trying to install quandl to use in Jupyter notebook. `py -m pip install quandl`

But I get the following error that SSL module in Python is not available.

````
Collecting quandl
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/quandl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/quandl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/quandl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/quandl/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/quandl/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/quandl/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/quandl/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement quandl (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for quandl
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping```

*******************************************************************************************************
I tried using the following, but nothing worked

```py -m pip install --trusted-host=pypi.org --trusted-host=files.pythonhosted.org --user quandl```
````

Comment: Has anyone got a viable answer for this issue?  I am experiencing the same issue with both an OSGeo4W64 installation and a QGIS 3.10 ltr installation.  I have plugins that require third party packages and I am unable to install them.

Comment: reference:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Anaconda, then add the following in environment paths:-

```
D:\Anaconda3; 
D:\Anaconda3\Scripts; 
D:\Anaconda3\Library\bin;
```

Comment: I have seen this posted elsewhere. I added this in "System Environment Variables" under "PATH". But it is not working. Is that the correct way? Or are you saying add to Conda/Anaconda?

Comment: You need to restart the terminal/command prompt after you edit the environment path.

Comment: Thanks Rohit. I did that. Still getting the same error: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.

Comment: Sadly, this is not an answer if Anaconda is not part of the installation. What if it was installed as part of QGIS?  Or OSGeo4W64? I have no issues at all with a standard Python 3.7 installation, but cannot pip install anything in the QGIS interpreter due to this error.  Adding the interpreter paths (ex: `C:\Program Files\QGIS 3.10\apps\Python37\Scripts`) did nothing to fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling python in the directory where you intend to install pip.

Then install pip and you should be good to go.