# Trying to install pandas-datareader for Anaconda 3.0 - CondaHTTPError:

Tags: python, pandas, anaconda, conda

How can I fix this and instal the pandas-datareader package in my windows 10?

This is my manual to install, but it´s not working.

---

INSTALLATION OF READER PANDAS FOR ANACONDA JUPITER
in
C: \ Users \ sergi \ Anaconda3 \ Scripts

stand on the folder (Scripts)
and with the keyboard {shift + button} and right mouse button, choose

{open the window with powershell here}

and paste the command

conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader

but add on
. \ (use alt graf for )

the command to paste would be

. \ conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader

---

The Windows Powershell said:

PS C:\Users\sergi\Anaconda3\Scripts> .\conda install -c anaconda pandas-datareader
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): failed

CondaHTTPError: HTTP 000 CONNECTION FAILED for url https://conda.anaconda.org/anaconda/win-64/current_repodata.json
Elapsed: -

An HTTP error occurred when trying to retrieve this URL.
HTTP errors are often intermittent, and a simple retry will get you on your way.
SSLError(MaxRetryError('HTTPSConnectionPool(host=\'conda.anaconda.org\', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /anaconda/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError("Can\'t connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available."))'))

PS C:\Users\sergi\Anaconda3\Scripts>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54932141/548562

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["SSL module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: the problem was that I needed to activate the administrator user in CMD. Now it´s working very well.