# python 3.6.10 pip3 TLS/SSL not configured

Tags: python-3.x, ssl, pip

I'm a begginer in Python, and some problems are happening. This is a script for installing python 3.6.10:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev
apt-get install -y libxml2-dev libxslt1-dev libffi-dev libssl-dev
apt-get install -y libgdal-dev
apt-get install -y tor
apt-get install -y unzip
apt-get install -y s3cmd
apt-get install -y libfreetype6-dev
apt-get install -y pkg-config
apt-get install -y qt5-default
apt-get install -y libqt5webkit5-dev
apt-get install -y texinfo
apt-get install -qy firefox xvfb
apt-get install -y tree
apt-get install -y htop
apt-get install -y chromium-browser

sudo apt-get install build-essential checkinstall 
sudo apt-get install libreadline-gplv2-dev libncursesw5-dev libsqlite3-dev tk-dev libgdbm-dev libc6-dev libbz2-dev

cd /opt
sudo wget https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.10/Python-3.6.10.tgz

sudo tar -xvf Python-3.6.10.tgz

cd Python-3.6.10
sudo ./configure --with-ssl


sudo make
sudo make install


sudo apt-get install -y build-essential python-pip python3-pip git
sudo -H pip install --upgrade pip
sudo -H pip3 install --upgrade pip
```

The installation seems to work properly, except by the pip3. Errors are occuring, and I didn't find the solution for that.

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages (18.1)
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.",)) - skipping
```

How can I fix it? And why it's happening?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42328420/7954504, specifically `libssl-dev`, and re-make

Comment: Hi, Brad! Unfortunately, it not worked. I have already installed libssl-dev. Tried to install all the packages you suggested in the post, but it still not worked

Comment: why do you `apt install` pip, does the installation of python you are compiling from source not come with pip already?

Comment: it was already in the script I used. But even without it, nothing different happened. This problem with pip3 happens anytime I try to use pip3. For example, install pandas or other package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly: your build of Python should allow you to use `python3 -m pip` as your `pip` command.  The `-m` flag is [good practice anyway](https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/) as it will make sure that you're associating the `pip` you use with the correct Python interpreter.  So, the `python-pip python3-pip` install should not be necessary.*

Secondly: with regards to the SSL option, it's possible you might need `python-openssl`.  I am, ironically, getting a server-side error when I try to search for this on packages.ubuntu.com, but it's shown in [this up to date example](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems) alongside `libssl-dev`.

[Here](https://gist.github.com/bsolomon1124/d67154474d4534c7170c76b5e7490fed) is a Dockerfile demonstrating both of the above points:

```
docker image build -f Dockerfile.60814903 -t so60814903:1 .
docker container run -it --rm so60814903:1
```

In that shell, you should see that you have `python3 -m pip` available.

Last tip, consider a solution that will help you manage multiple Python versions alongside each other.  [pyenv](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv) is one such tool, and there are others out there also.

---

<sub>Specifically, `./configure` by default will use `--with-ensurepip='upgrade'`.  [Here](https://github.com/docker-library/python/blob/905c16b0473668acb80f717494789c438ab0f0f9/3.9-rc/buster/Dockerfile) is an example of an installation that uses `--with-ensurepip=no` and installs pip separately.</sub>