# Trying to install SocialFish on kali linux

Tags: python, pip

```
root@hunter:~/SocialFish# python3 -m pip install -r requirements.txt
```

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Collecting requests==2.20.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
  Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/requests/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests==2.20.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1)) (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests==2.20.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping

Comment: Looks like maybe your python3 was not compiled with all the necessary libraries? If you google that error code theres some results that appear to address your issue: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)

Comment: thank for helping , but the link you ref i had already tried.As you said it was a compiling error. so i reinstall (overwrite) python 3 and instead of using pip3 install i use pip3 install. the issue was fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have reinstall python3 and make sure it was compile well then instead of using pip i used pip3.

because what i learn that pip come with python2 installation package, please someone correct me if am wrong

thank you.

Comment: You might want to read this: https://snarky.ca/why-you-should-use-python-m-pip/