# How to resolve SSLError preventing package installation?

Tags: python-3.x

I tried to output top 250 movies according to imdb rating with python. When I type the code as in the  following screenshot1

```py
import imdb
ia = imdb.IMDb()
search = ia.get_top250_movies()
for i in range(10):
    print(search[i])
```

It gave me error saying no module imdb. So, I tried to install imdb python file with command `pip install imdbpy`, but still gave me the  error as:

```py
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement imdbpy (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for imdbpy
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/:
There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate:
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443):
Max retries exceeded with url:
/simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

Comment: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available. Install the ssl module

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney : I am really new to programming and trying to learn python in this current situation. So, please bare with me if I ask simple and silly questions. So, as per your instruction, I tried to install SSL with the command: pip install ssl. It is giving me the same error.

Comment: Maybe this answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in/57240184

Comment: I don't know if it works .Check your system time is up to date or not , just in case.

Comment: @Solen'ya my system time is up to date

Comment: How did you install python?  Just downloaded python or is this anaconda or something else?  What OS?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney it is anaconda

Comment: Try `conda update conda` then `conda update --all` and the anaconda prompt.

Comment: It could possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3 As Trenton McKinney said you should try upgrading the anaconda. The problem arises because you don't have SSL support installed, you would need to install the OpenSSL for Python.

Comment: Also try `conda update openssl` and or `conda upgrade openssl`.

Comment: [“ssl module in Python is not available” when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: One other note, if you have multiple installations of python, for instance a system python and another from Anaconda, make sure you are using the the Anaconda prompt.