# In my vitual env while installing flask receiving this error "Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement Flask (from versions: )"

Tags: python, flask

I have created virtual environment venv where i am trying to install flask. But it is showing me following error.

[image]

Guys please help me solving these problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide the the actuall stack trace and not an image of it .Take a look at this for some guidelines [ask] . :D

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ssl module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)