# Not being able to install requests with pip3

Tags: python, pip, kali-linux

In my 2020.3 release Kali
When i try to install requests with pip3 i get this error ...Can anybody help me i'm not being able to understand it

```
root@kali:~# pip3 install requests
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/requests/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/requests/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/requests/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement requests (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for requests
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
root@kali:~#
```

Comment: Do you have python and pip installed?

Comment: Did you try this [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64425147/not-being-able-to-install-requests-with-pip3)

Comment: Yes i have both python and pip installed

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ssl module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Answer (score 0):

hmm I think I entered the wrong link. I meant trying this ->[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in)
Basically, you need homebrew if you are on Mac.

Comment: Oops i'm not in mac :(

Comment: in that same link there is an answer for Debian. Try that

Comment: E: Unable to locate package libtk8.5
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libtk8.5'
again got this error from the solution through that link