# Python get-pip.py fails due to site-package not writtable and SSL not available while they seem OK

Tags: python, linux, pip

I'm working on a Linux machine `Scientific Linux release 6.10 (Carbon)` administrated by my Company (I don't have admin privileges here).

This machine has some Python 2 versions installed, but I need a Python 3 to run a script.

So I downloaded Python source and ran `configure`, `make` (not `make install` as I'm not admin).

Now I need pip some install some packages, so I downloaded https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py and I run `python get-pip.py`, but now I'm getting a warning and an error:

"Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable"

When I check privileges of `site-packages` folder it's fully accessible (`-rwxrwxrwx`) so what's wrong?

And then the script reports:

```
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/pip/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pip (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pip
```

While SSL is definitely available `openssl version -a` reports me the version installed.

What's wrong? Is it all due to the fact that I did not run `make install`?

Comment: Esp. this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45417908/7976758. OpenSSL is available but development files (headers and libraries) are not. You need to install them and recompile Python.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+WARNING%3A+pip+is+configured+with+locations+that+require+TLS%2FSSL%2C+however+the+ssl+module+in+Python+is+not+available

Comment: I would recommend `
mkdir $HOME/usr &&
./configure --prefix=$HOME/usr && make install
`

Then you can do

`
$HOME/usr/bin/python get-pip.py
`