# Python virtualenv pip install gives ssl error

Tags: python, ssl, pip

Okay so I'm trying to set up a virtualenv (on legacy server btw) (python3.6.9, ubuntu 18.10), but whenever I try to install packages for it I get

```
pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
```

This is the case for `pip`, `pip3`, `pip3.6`, `python -m pip`, `python3 -m pip` and `python3.6 -m pip`.
I have tried reinstalling python, pip, virtualenv and other stuff, but it seems to persist whatever I try.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ssl module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: Tried the comments under questions and all the answers that didnt need OSX, windows/anaconda or CentOS, and they didn't work =/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I found something that worked.
The ssl was apparently more broken than I expected, but thanks to the fact that we had a second server which did function normally, I was able to copy the file (for those interested: `cp /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so tmp`, then connect SFTP Net drive to extract tmp, connect to other server and insert tmp, then `cp tmp /usr/local/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload/_ssl.cpython-36m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so`) and that made it function (almost) normally (small warnings aside).