# Installing keras in R: WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available

Tags: r, tensorflow, ssl, keras

I am new to keras and was trying to install keras and tensorflow in R on my computer running Windows 10 using [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/keras/vignettes/index.html) guide but get the error in the title:

```
install_keras()

Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): ...working... done
Solving environment: ...working... done

All requested packages already installed.

WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")': /simple/tensorflow/
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/tensorflow/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/tensorflow/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.6.* (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.6.*
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module in Python is not available.
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
Error: Error installing package(s): "\"tensorflow==2.6.*\"", "\"tensorflow-hub\"", "\"scipy\"", "\"requests\"", "\"Pillow\"", "\"h5py\"", "\"pandas\""
```

I tried installing OpenSSL due to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3) question and also tried copying dll's as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45954528/pip-is-configured-with-locations-that-require-tls-ssl-however-the-ssl-module-in), but nothing works.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So, I found a solution myself. I did:

```
library(reticulate)
install_miniconda(force = TRUE)
```

From the command prompt in Windows, I did:

```
conda activate r-reticulate
install keras
```

... and everything worked!

Seems to work now even though I do not activate the r-reticulate environment.

Comment: should have ended with `conda install keras` not `install keras`