# Can't install pymc3 getting 'NameError: name 'CERT_NONE' is not defined

Tags: python, ssl, command-line, anaconda, conda

I am trying to get pymc3 installed and running on anaconda. I have tried installing the package in the command line, anaconda prompt and directly in anaconda via environments and neither work. I get the following error when I try to import pymc3

```
import pymc3

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymc3'
```

[here is the warning I get when I attempt to use pip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FlTiL.png)

and when I try to use conda
 `conda install -c conda-forge pymc3`
I get the following warning error

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda-script.py", line 12, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main.py", line 152, in main
    return conda_exception_handler(_main, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1371, in conda_exception_handler
    return_value = exception_handler(func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1082, in __call__
    return self.handle_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1126, in handle_exception
    return self.handle_unexpected_exception(exc_val, exc_tb)
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1137, in handle_unexpected_exception
    self.print_unexpected_error_report(error_report)
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\exceptions.py", line 1207, in print_unexpected_error_report
    from .cli.main_info import get_env_vars_str, get_main_info_str
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\cli\main_info.py", line 19, in <module>
    from ..core.index import _supplement_index_with_system
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\index.py", line 13, in <module>
    from .package_cache_data import PackageCacheData
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\package_cache_data.py", line 14, in <module>
    from .path_actions import CacheUrlAction, ExtractPackageAction
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\core\path_actions.py", line 30, in <module>
    from ..gateways.connection.download import download
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\conda\gateways\connection\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from requests import ConnectionError, HTTPError, Session
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\__init__.py", line 52, in <module>
    from . import utils
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\utils.py", line 23, in <module>
    from .compat import parse_http_list as _parse_list_header
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\compat.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .packages import charade as chardet
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from . import urllib3
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    from .connectionpool import (
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py", line 45, in <module>
    from .util import get_host, is_connection_dropped, ssl_wrap_socket
  File "C:\Users\13038\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\packages\urllib3\util.py", line 293, in <module>
    def ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile=None, certfile=None, cert_reqs=CERT_NONE,
NameError: name 'CERT_NONE' is not defined
```

Clearly this has something to do with my SSL but I am not very savvy with security and the command line. I should also mention I tried to use the anaconda prompt.

Thanks,

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ssl module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: @kHarshit unfortunately this only works for Ubuntu. I should add I'm Running Windows 10