# pip3 install on mac os not working - need help troubleshooting

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to run the pip command and install a dependency on mac os but I am just getting an error message that looks like this

```
Could not fetch URL https://pypi.org/simple/pip/: There was a problem confirming the ssl certificate: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /simple/pip/ (Caused by SSLError("Can't connect to HTTPS URL because the SSL module is not available.")) - skipping
```

I added a picture below to best understand. Can anyone help me figure this out?

I also tried reinstalling python and that didnt work either - I just keep getting the same message

I also tried pip3 and I get the same error

Comment: Did you try the solution shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3 ?

Comment: Doesn't python -m pip work?

Comment: @MATOS I tried it and it doesnt work

Comment: Python -m pip3?

Comment: nope, getting a message that says no module named pip3

Comment: any other recs?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `python -m ensurepip`

If that doesn't work, try installing [openSSL](https://help.dreamhost.com/hc/en-us/articles/360001435926-Installing-OpenSSL-locally-under-your-username), and only if that *still* doesn't work, do `./configure -–with-openssl=/home/username/openssl` and then `python3 -m ssl`.

Answer (score -2):

try this
pip3 install ddtrace

MacOS is different according to windows. MacOS uses pip

Comment: I tried pip3 and i get the same error message

Answer (score -3):

on Mac you have to use `pip3`

`pip` is for Windows

Comment: i tried pip3 and I get the same message