# problem in installing and running pip3.10 on raspbery pi

Tags: python-3.x, raspberry-pi

I have manually installed python 3.10.7 following this guide: https://aruljohn.com/blog/python-raspberrypi/ (I just want to have the latest python on the rpi)

how ever when i try to install any python packages using pip3.10 i get:

```
Executing: pip3.10 install --upgrade pipenv

Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
WARNING: pip is configured with locations that require TLS/SSL, however the ssl module 
in Python is not available.
```

am i missing out on something?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["ssl module in Python is not available" when installing package with pip3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3)

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it