# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl' error

Tags: python, ssl, openssl, python-3.10, pyopenssl

What is this error for?
**import ssl
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 1, in 
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 99, in 
import _ssl             # if we can't import it, let the error propagate
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ssl'**

`[root@xemonserver ~]# openssl version OpenSSL 1.0.2k-fips  26 Jan 2017`

I tried many methods, but I still have the same problem
The operating system is Centos7 and python version 3.10.11

[method 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41328451/ssl-module-in-python-is-not-available-when-installing-package-with-pip3) that doesn't work

Comment: The 'method 1' you refer to suggests installing a number of packages via apt-get, THEN reinstalling (or updating) the Python packages (and pip3  to be safe). How far did you get with that?

Comment: not enough info given for Q