# linux ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes

Tags: python, linux, centos

```html
[root@ONEVPS190105040754 ~]# youtube-dl -V
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/__main__.py", line 16, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/options.py", line 8, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/downloader/__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/downloader/common.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/bin/youtube-dl/youtube_dl/compat.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/python3/lib/python3.7/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
[root@ONEVPS190105040754 ~]# yum  install libffi-dev
Loaded plugins: changelog, fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.metrocast.net
 * extras: mirrors.maine.edu
 * updates: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
No package libffi-dev available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

I was going to use youtube-dl, but told me "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'". I found some methods on the Internet, such as "yum install libffi-dev", but they still didn't work

Centos7

Comment: Have you tried the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045929/6804636 ( sudo apt-get install libffi-dev )?

Answer (score 7):

This solved the same error for me on CentOS7:

```
yum install libffi-devel
```

Reference: [issue31652](https://bugs.python.org/issue31652)

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` worked for me on Debian (probably same on Ubuntu).

Comment: `yum install` first, and then do you need to remake Python from source? I think you need to(?)

Comment: Yes it worked. I've yum installed ```libffi-devel```, rebuilt and then could successfully install scikit-bio (for I had the same '_ctypes' error).

Answer (score 1):

> From [this post](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/94#issuecomment-877227) :

It's a problem with your Python installation: it seems to be missing the `_ctypes.so` library. In this Debian system, it's `/usr/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/_ctypes.so`. If you do have a `lib-dynload` directory, append it to the `\$PYTHONPATH` environment variable and see if it helps. (To test, open the interactive shell and try `import _ctypes`. To see the current path, use `import sys` and `sys.path`.)

Consider using the packaged version of Python if your operating system offers one.

(As a last resort, you can comment out the import `ctypes line`; it is only used with the `--console-title` option on Win32.)

> Try above, see if it solve your problem.

Comment: where is the ctypes line located?