# Trouble with pip when upgrading python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip

I have linux mint that came with python 2.7 and python 3.4. I downloaded python 3.7 per the instruction here: 
https://tecadmin.net/install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-linuxmint/

Now when I type `python` in the terminal, I get python 2.7, when I enter `python3` I get python 3.4 and when I enter `python3.7` I get python 3.7. The problem is that whenever I enter `pip -V`, I get "pip 18.1 is from /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/pip (python 2.7)", when I use `pip3 -V`, I get "pip 18.1 is from /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pip (python 3.4), and when I run the command `python3.7 -m pip -V` I get the error "/usr/local/bin/python3.7: No module named pip".

How do I get pip to realize that I have python 3.7 now? It's an issue because I'm trying to download a package that won't download unless python 3.5+ is installed.

Comment: you can use `python3.7 -m pip` to manage the packages of the 3.7 interpreter

Comment: Yes but then I get the "no module named pip" error which confuses me because python 3.7 should automatically come with pip...

Comment: you should be able to bootstrap pip with `python3.7 -m ensurepip`

Answer (score 1):

The mistake I made is that I was missing a few python3.7 prerequisites. Downloading the packages listed in: [Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul/41310760) and then reinstalling python 3.7 got pip installed. Now when I enter `pip3.7 -V` I get "pip 18.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pip (python 3.7) which is what I need.