# C# - Python interop using Python.Net [No module named '_ctypes']

Tags: c#, python, interop, python.net

I am trying to use [Python.NET](https://github.com/pythonnet/pythonnet) to perform interop between C# and Python on a Windows machine.

Specifically I have the following code.

```
PythonEngine.PythonHome = @"C:\Python\3_5_4";
PythonEngine.PythonPath = @"C:\Python\3_5_4\Lib;C:\Python\3_5_4\Lib\site-packages";

using (Python.Runtime.Py.GIL())
{
    dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
    dynamic sin = np.sin;
    Console.WriteLine(sin);
}
```

While I can successfully execute a general python statement as such:

```
var res = PythonEngine.Eval("1 + 1");
Console.WriteLine(res);
//res = 2
```

Which indicates that the python engine itself is working successfully, I can also invoke something like this:

```
var html = Py.Import("html");
Console.WriteLine(html);
//html = <module 'html' from 'C:\\Python\\3_5_4\\Lib\\html\\__init__.py'>
```

Which further indicates that the module loading functionality is also working correctly.

However whenever I attempt to invoke the line:

```
dynamic np = Py.Import("numpy");
```

I receive the following error:

`{"ImportError : No module named '_ctypes'"}`.

```
['  File "C:\\Python\\3_5_4\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>\n    from . import _distributor_init\n', '  File "C:\\Python\\3_5_4\\Lib\\site-packages\\numpy\\_distributor_init.py", line 9, in <module>\n    from ctypes import WinDLL\n', '  File "C:\\Python\\3_5_4\\Lib\\ctypes\\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>\n    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array\n']
```

The file referenced is located @ 'C:\Python\3_5_4\Lib\ctypes\__init__.py'.

I have verified that all the expected paths are set correctly and that the Ctypes folder exists in my python path.

I have tried everything from uninstalling and reinstalling Python to modifying the `ctypes/__init__.py` file to try and import Ctypes directly to no effect.

Having researched this topic online throughly I have found a number of suggestions which point to running `yum install libffi-devel` [as detailed here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul). However this does not appear to be something that I can perform on windows given that yum appears to be a Linux only application.

Can anyone provide any guidance?

Comment: Python version 3 will only work with path lengths up to ~120 characters.  It appears that your path length are ok.  When calling  a script from c# in a Process Class you have no environmental variables.  So if your python script is expecting a environmental variable it will not work.  So try from cmd.exe >Set which will show all the normal windows environmental variables.  See if any are used by python.

Comment: The comment above states two facts, and both are in fact completely wrong. There is no 120 character limit. And environment variables are inherited.

Comment: @maxim Can you `import numpy` from a Python interpreter?

Comment: did you ever resolve this issue? @Maxim Gershkovich