# Unable to install scipy on Ubuntu

Tags: python, scipy, installation, failed-installation

I am trying to install scipy on Linux (Ubuntu):

I am using the following command:

```
pip install scipy
```

But I got this error:

```
Collecting scipy
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/ee/5b/5afcd1c46f97b3c2ac3489dbc95d6ca28eacf8e3634e51f495da68d97f0f/scipy-1.3.1.tar.gz
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-x5wy9z29/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools 'Cython>=0.29.2' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
       cwd: None
  Complete output (28 lines):
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.5" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version >= "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment
  Collecting wheel
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/00/83/b4a77d044e78ad1a45610eb88f745be2fd2c6d658f9798a15e384b7d57c9/wheel-0.33.6-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting setuptools
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d9/de/554b6310ac87c5b921bc45634b07b11394fe63bc4cb5176f5240addf18ab/setuptools-41.6.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
  Collecting Cython>=0.29.2
    Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/a5/1f/c7c5450c60a90ce058b47ecf60bb5be2bfe46f952ed1d3b95d1d677588be/Cython-0.29.13.tar.gz
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uksqh3vn/Cython/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-uksqh3vn/Cython/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-uksqh3vn/Cython/pip-egg-info
           cwd: /tmp/pip-install-uksqh3vn/Cython/
      Complete output (11 lines):
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
          from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
          from setuptools import windows_support
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
          import ctypes
        File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
          from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
      ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
      ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
  ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: /usr/local/bin/python3 /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix /tmp/pip-build-env-x5wy9z29/overlay --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- wheel setuptools 'Cython>=0.29.2' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.5'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version>='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' Check the logs for full command output.
```

I used the same command to install numpy:

```
pip install numpy
```

And works perfectly.

Edit: When I put:

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

I got:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python-scipy is already the newest version (0.17.0-1).
```

But if I just put in my code:

```
import scipy
```

I got:

```
Python 3.8.0 (default, Oct 29 2019, 14:49:17) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import scipy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy'
```

Comment: You have multiple installs: currently you have Python 3.8, but the error messages from the failed installation tell you it finds components from previous installs under Python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7. See all the existing questions about either using Anaconda, or virtual environments.

Comment: That `ModuleNotFounderror` on `_ctypes` is suspicious. Can you also _import_ numpy, or does it raise an error when you try?

Comment: if it's an option, it might be a good idea to clear every unnecessary python version you had, and then work with 1 nice setup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3: ImportError: No module named '\_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

Comment: I got the same error with `import numpy`. @AndrasDeak

Comment: This doesn't work @ParitoshSingh

Comment: That's why I suspected. Your base python installation is incomplete. See the duplicate Paritosh linked, it tells you how to install libffi before rebuilding your python (assuming you built python from source yourself).

Answer (score 3):

You can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install python3-numpy python3-scipy
```

Or

```
sudo apt-get install python-scipy
```

Comment: I edited the post with more informations. Thank you.

Comment: In this case as mentioned @smci you could better create and use env as you’ve multiple python versions. This can be managed easily in Anaconda.