# There's a problem when I compile py file to apk through buildozer

Tags: python, android, kivy, buildozer

When compile a very simple "Hello World" kivy file to apk. But an error occured.

## I am nervous. This is the log:

```
[INFO]:    -> running autogen.sh
Exception in thread background thread for pid 10006:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:

  RAN: /mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 668, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 33, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_127:

  RAN: /mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh: 2: exec: autoreconf: not found
```

=============================================================================
It's just a pretty simple py with kivy file but I don't expected to get this Error.
So Please Help me!!
Many Thanks!!!

Update: After installed autoconf, I tried to compile again, but another error occured.

Log:

```
Exception in thread background thread for pid 9679:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 1540, in wrap
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 2459, in background_thread
    handle_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 2157, in fn
    return self.command.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1


  STDERR:


Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 184, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 1192, in <module>
    main()
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/entrypoints.py", line 18, in main
    ToolchainCL()
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 668, in __init__
    getattr(self, args.subparser_name.replace('-', '_'))(args)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 153, in wrapper_func
    build_dist_from_args(ctx, dist, args)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/toolchain.py", line 206, in build_dist_from_args
    args, "ignore_setup_py", False
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/build.py", line 577, in build_recipes
    recipe.build_arch(arch)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/recipes/libffi/__init__.py", line 33, in build_arch
    shprint(sh.Command('./autogen.sh'), _env=env)
  File "/mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/python-for-android/pythonforandroid/logger.py", line 180, in shprint
    for line in output:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 863, in next
    self.wait()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 792, in wait
    self.handle_command_exit_code(exit_code)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/sh-1.12.14-py3.5.egg/sh.py", line 815, in handle_command_exit_code
    raise exc
sh.ErrorReturnCode_1:

  RAN: /mnt/d/project1/test/.buildozer/android/platform/build-armeabi-v7a/build/other_builds/libffi/armeabi-v7a__ndk_target_21/libffi/autogen.sh

  STDOUT:
autoreconf: Entering directory `.'
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Gettext
autoreconf: running: aclocal --force -I m4
autoreconf: configure.ac: tracing
autoreconf: configure.ac: not using Libtool
autoreconf: running: /usr/bin/autoconf --force
configure.ac:41: error: possibly undefined macro: AC_PROG_LIBTOOL
      If this token and others are legitimate, please use m4_pattern_allow.
      See the Autoconf documentation.
autoreconf: /usr/bin/autoconf failed with exit status: 1


  STDERR:
```

I need to compile it now, but I don't know how to fix it. Please help me again! Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `libtool` library. This command should solve your problem.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libtool
```

[Reference link](https://github.com/ffi/ffi/issues/606#issuecomment-363420210)

[This might help you as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

Answer (score -1):

You need to install the `autoconf` package:

```
sudo apt-get install autoconf
```