# Python - numpy: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python

I have to run a python 3 script on a centos 7 host. I've installed python3.8 side by side with python2 so it doesn't break yum.

When I'm running the script I need to run I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "A2PTestSuit.py", line 8, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 16, in <module>
    raise ImportError(
ImportError: Unable to import required dependencies:
numpy: No module named '_ctypes'
```

If I list the modules I see that pandas and numpy are installed:

```
python3 -m pip list
Package         Version
--------------- ----------
certifi         2019.11.28
chardet         3.0.4
DateTime        4.3
idna            2.8
numpy           1.18.1
pandas          0.25.3
pip             19.3.1
python-dateutil 2.8.1
pytz            2019.3
requests        2.22.0
setuptools      41.2.0
six             1.13.0
urllib3         1.25.7
zope.interface  4.7.1
```

How can I get past this error?

Comment: Another answer - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul - suggests to `yum install libffi-devel`

Comment: I've tried that, but it looks like it's already installed: `Package libffi-devel-3.0.13-18.el7.x86_64 already installed and lates t version Nothing to do` I've installed all the other modules using pip. Can I mix pip and yum module installs like that?

Answer (score 1):

You can try updating all of your packages in the command line using pip, or just use `try: import ... except ImportError: continue`

Comment: I fixed it by recompiling with the `sudo make -j 8` command. No errors after recompiling with that command.

Answer (score 1):

I've got same issue. Problem was solved after I change default interpreter (which was Python 3.8) in PyCharm