# Mime Type Issue Loading CSS With Django App

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, heroku, mime-types

I have a Django app hosted on Heroku, and my stylesheet isn't loading. Now I've taken the time to read the other questions on this issue, but I believe each situation is unique. Now the error is as follows:

> Refused to apply style from 'https://mazzodjangoapp.herokuapp.com/static/blog/main.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

The static directory is defined in my settings.py file as:

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

In my base.html file, my link tag looks like this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'blog/main.css' %}">
```

Works locally. Why is it not loading up in the Heroku environment?

Answer (score 6):

As per the Heroku guide for configuring Django apps, you need to use pip and install django_heroku

```
pip install django_heroku
```

Add it to your settings.py

```
import django_heroku
```

And finally, add this to the bottom of the settings.py file

```
django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

Answer (score 3):

Using white noise in my project worked for me. since [I had system errors and I couldn't install Django-Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul).

[Here](http://whitenoise.evans.io/en/stable/django.html) is the link I used to set up my white noise.

Basically

1. Install white noise

   `pip install whitenoise`
2. Add it to middleware

   ```
   MIDDLEWARE = [

   django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',

   'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

    #...

   ]
   ```

and that's all. you then send your code to Heroku

Answer (score 2):

**"whitenoise"** can solve **"MIME type" error** to load **CSS** successfully:

This is how you use **"whitenoise"**:

First, install **"whitenoise"**:

```
pip install whitenoise
```

Then,  set it to **"MIDDLEWARE"** in **"settings.py"**. That's it to load **CSS** successfully:

```py
MIDDLEWARE = [
    # ...
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware", # Here
    # ...
]
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to run `$ python manage.py collectstatic` before pushing to Heroku.

Comment: For anyone deploying a Django app to DigitalOcean... this is also true.

You cannot run `collectstatic` from the console... you need to include the output in your git repo.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that `DEBUG = False` in `settings.py`