# Heroku can't load my css file because its a mimetype

Tags: python, django, heroku, web-deployment, django-staticfiles

I deployed my website it all works and main css loaded but for some reason my another css refusing to load in the console it say

> Refused to apply style from '......' because its MIME type
> ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME
> checking is enabled.

This is my setting.py Am i missing something ?

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
BASE_DIR / "static",
BASE_DIR / 'media',
]

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static_cdn')
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn')


TEMP = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media_cdn/temp')
```

Comment: Have you tried this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60910720/11475846

Comment: yup, now it is now servererror (500)

Comment: 30 mins later i tried it again. now it show the same result again

Answer (score 0):

Heroku is case-sensitive when it comes to static files.

The problem was with the Django template -:

```
{% static "static\css\Client\style.css"%}
```

The directory(client) was having its name in all smallcaps, while it was being mentioned as Client in titlecase, a directory of that name did not exist and thus heroku was not able to find the directory specified, changing the directory to smallcaps in my Django template worked like so -:

```
{% static "static\css\client\style.css"%}
```