# Openpyxl Pip Install Error: Command Errored Out

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, openpyxl

I continue to receive the following error when trying to install openpyxl:

```
pip install openpyxl
Collecting openpyxl
  Using cached openpyxl-3.0.3.tar.gz (172 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/bigdata/scripts/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eztesmv9/openpyxl/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-eztesmv9/openpyxl/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-eztesmv9/openpyxl/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-eztesmv9/openpyxl/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/home/bigdata/scripts/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution, Feature
      File "/home/bigdata/scripts/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 36, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/home/bigdata/scripts/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/home/bigdata/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

Based on other posts, I have already tried the following commands:

```
python3 -m ensurepip --upgrade
pip install --upgrade setuptools
pip install -U pip
```

With each of them returning:

```
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools in /home/bigdata/scripts/lib/python3.8/site-packages (45.1.0)
```

Am I missing something? We just migrated our account over to an A2 Hosting VPS server and I am unfamiliar with most of the setup. Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: what does `pip --version` return?

Comment: It seems you have a broken (incomplete) installation of Python 3.8. How did you install it into `/home/bigdata/scripts/lib/python3.8`? Did you compile it from sources? in that case you need to [recompile](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045929/7976758) to enable `ctypes` module.

Comment: Pip version returns: pip 20.0.2 from /home/bigdata/scripts/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

I installed python by following the instructions my host gave me at: https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/developer-corner/python/using-a-newer-version-of-python

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this issue by reinstalling python, following the clue from phd that I may have a broken install.