# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctype'

Tags: python, discord

I am trying to install a discord bot on my server. While trying to run the file, it returned a lot of errors.

I don't have a requirements.txt file since I only need one module - discord.py.
I am also doing this in a virtual environment.

In the end it showed this:
from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

Comment: Your post is unclear to me. Obviously you try to run something on a server, but you did not provide relevant information like if you're using a virtual environment, what's the content of a requirements.txt (if available). Everything else is just fishing in cloudy.

Comment: @mosesontheweb Sorry, I have made some edits to the question. I don't have a requirements file. I only need a discord module which I have already installed via pip.

Comment: There are some answers with a lot of upvotes to a question with the same error text as you here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul . Did you check if those answers are relevant?

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if it works with Discord, but I solved "from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'" error, doing:

1. If you are using pyenv or virtualenv and Linux, I suggest, install or reinstall all the dependencies below (Ubuntu and derivatives):
   make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python3-openssl
2. Next, I suggest you recreate you python installation (at virtual enviroment), pls, DO NOT reinstall the original Python from the system.
   I replaced(a fresh installation) pyenv with Python 3.9.16 to pyenv Python 3.10.9 and the error is over.
3. And the final suggest, if you are developer and are using Pycharm, when pycharm ask you about if you wanna install cython, answer "yes".

I hope this tips help you. good luck there!