# Python - pip3.7 can't install virtualenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper

Good morning guys

I ended up creating several Python builds (2.7.18, 3.6.10, 3.7.7, 3.8.2, 3.9.0) downloading the tar.gz for each of these versions and creating the build.

I know that it is recommended to use only the pip of one of them and then create a virtual environment, however, I want to have the flexibility to use the pip of any of these versions to install the dependencies because that way I can create an alias for both pip and python and change the versions whenever I want.

When I went to install virtualenv with python 3.7.7 pip3.7, I am getting the following error:

[image: virtualenv]

I was able to install requests and NumPy, so I would like to know if virtualenv can in fact be installed in versions above 3.6, below you can see the correct installations.

[image: numpy]

[image: requests]

Anyone who can help would be grateful.

Comment: This is a common problem for when you haven't installed all of the prerequisites for your OS. Please see [this page](https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/wiki/Common-build-problems) and double-check that you've installed everything correctly beforehand.

Comment: Thanks, Hampus your answer combined with the one that Jeremy provided helped me to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### 1 - Install Essential Dependencies

Installing the dependencies below, mainly `libffi-dev` for systems like Ubuntu/Mint/ Debian and `libffi-devel` for systems like Fedora/ CentOS:

#### Ubuntu/Mint/Debian

```
sudo apt-get install -y make build-essential libssl-dev zlib1g-dev libbz2-dev \
libreadline-dev libsqlite3-dev wget curl llvm libncurses5-dev libncursesw5-dev \
xz-utils tk-dev libffi-dev liblzma-dev python-openssl git
```

#### Fedora/CentOS

```
sudo yum install @development zlib-devel bzip2 bzip2-devel readline-devel sqlite \
sqlite-devel openssl-devel xz xz-devel libffi-devel findutils
```

#### 2 - Installing Python

After installing the above dependencies, if you are creating manually, you must perform the procedures below:

- Remove the version you generated earlier
- Run ./configure
- Run make
- Run sudo make altinstall

This way you will be able to install all dependencies without any errors.

Answer (score 0):

According to the following question, you should install `libffi-devel`:

[Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

Comment: Thanks, Jeremy your answer combined with the one that Hampus provided helped me to solve my issue.
Below I will include all the steps that I've done to solve my problem.