# ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1 with sudo pip3.8 install websocket,

Tags: python-3.x, pip

like i put on the title when i put pip install websockets to install on a rasberry pi, like said on this website https://pypi.org/project/websockets/ it puts this error

```
Looking in indexes: https://pypi.org/simple, https://www.piwheels.org/simple
Collecting websocket
  Using cached https://www.piwheels.org/simple/websocket/websocket-0.2.1-py3-none-any.whl (191 kB)
Collecting greenlet
  Using cached greenlet-0.4.16.tar.gz (60 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3.8 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1r2o5cjv/greenlet/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-1r2o5cjv/greenlet/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-u9pmz3n4
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-1r2o5cjv/greenlet/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

versions

-pip 20.1.1 from /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pip (python 3.8)

-Python 3.8.0

i've tried ***(this text had been had after the post had been published)*** :

this link [Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

and

Comment: By the `/usr/local/` prefix I can guess you've compiled your Python yourself. Your module `ctypes was not properly compiled.` You need to install necessary dependencies and recompile Python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3: ImportError: No module named '\_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython-3.x%5D+ModuleNotFoundError%3A+No+module+named+_ctypes

Comment: i've already tried but after doing `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` like said in the first answer and for debian/unbuntu, i get this error `/ bin / sh: 1: / usr / bin / apt-listchanges: not found
E: The / usr / bin / apt-listchanges --apt || subprocess test $? -lt 10 returned an error code (1)
E: Failure running script / usr / bin / apt-listchanges --apt || test $? -lt 10`when it puts an another error, I though that it didn't work with rasberrry pi. Thanks for helping, it's awesome to have this community

Comment: i will look at https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/ to upgrade my post

Comment: it's strange that on linux it imports a module name `windows_support`

Comment: `dist.py` [imports `windows_support`](https://github.com/pypa/setuptools/blob/213baae85f0b9c2640fdf7bf270f6b210f119c54/setuptools/dist.py#L34) unconditionally.

Comment: what do i need to do with it?

Comment: Nothing. You need to install `ctypes`' dependencies and recompile Python.

Comment: how can y do that?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install libffi-dev` or equivalent (using `apt`, `aptitude`, `dselect`). If there're problems you have to fix your Debian installation.

Comment: when i had error on error i just put on a usb key all the file that i needed to safe and re put debian from the begining. still thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command :

```
    python3.8 -m pip install ctypes
```

and then try the same installation procedure you did.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hie and thanks but he put's this error:` ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement ctypes (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for ctypes`

Comment: `ctypes` is [a part of stdlib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ctypes.html), you cannot install it separately.