# No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: python

I'm trying to install pyautogui, but pip keeps throwing errors. How to fix it? I've tried installing libffi library. Here is some code:

```
python3 -m pip install pyautogui
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Collecting pyautogui
  Using cached PyAutoGUI-0.9.50.tar.gz (57 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /usr/local/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sxm4ewnq/pyautogui/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-sxm4ewnq/pyautogui/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-85ugzov6
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-sxm4ewnq/pyautogui/
    Complete output (11 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
        from setuptools.dist import Distribution
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 34, in <module>
        from setuptools import windows_support
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/windows_support.py", line 2, in <module>
        import ctypes
      File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
        from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

That's from python REPL

```
>>> sys.path
['', '/home/walenty/apps/Python-3.8.5/Modules/_ctypes', '/usr/local/lib/python38.zip', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/lib-dynload', '/home/walenty/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages', '/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages']
>>> import _ctypes
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

Comment: Did you also try installing `libffi-dev` (specifically `-dev`)?

Comment: Yes, I've got this package too.

Comment: You may post your solution as short answer to your own question, steps that you've done. So that this question is not un-answered. And accept it as correct answer. You'll get some score points too for that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Required

Install foreign function interface headers

`sudo apt install libffi-dev`

## Reinstall Python

Substitute desired python version

### Ubuntu

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa -y && sudo apt install --reinstall python3.9-distutils`

### MacOS

Use `brew install python3.9` or `port install python3.9` (I recommend port)

### Windows

Use Microsoft Store

## Specify project python version

### Poetry

`poetry env use 3.9`

### Virtual envs

`virtualenv -p python3.9 myproject`

etc...

Answer (score 3):

okay, I've got it. This is the answer [Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

I cloned python3.10 from git and installed it from scratch.

Answer (score 3):

As other answers say, you need to install libffi-dev. If you're using pyenv/virtualenv, also reinstall the base python version:

Install libffi

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

Load the new libffi.so, as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045929/575060)

```
sudo ldconfig
```

Reinstall the python version available to pyenv

```
pyenv install 3.9.12
```

Finally, create the fresh virtualenv

```
pyenv virtualenv 3.9.12 new_environment
```

Answer (score 0):

Note if you are using an HPC cluster or similar where you don't have sudo access, try `module spider python`, then `module load python/version` to load a suitable python version.

You won't have to compile, meaning you won't have to install `libffi-dev`