# Python not using proper pip

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, pip, centos

I'm running CentOS 8 that came with native Python 3.6.8. I needed Python 3.7 so I installed Python 3.7.0 from sources. Now, `python` command is unknown to the system, while commands `python3` and `python3.7` both use Python 3.7.

All good until now, but I can't seem to get pip working.

Command `pip` returns command not found, while `python3 -m pip`, `python3.7 -m pip`, `python3 -m pip3`, and `python3.7 -m pip3` return `No module named pip`. Only pip command that works is `pip3`.

Now whatever package I install via `pip3` does not seem to install properly. Example given, `pip3 install tornado` returns `Requirement already satisfied`, but when I try to import tornado in Python 3.7 I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tornado'`. Not the same thing can be said when I try to import it in Python 3.6, which works flawlessly. From this, I understand that my pip only works with Python 3.6, and not with 3.7.

Please tell me how can I use pip with Python 3.7, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your `python3.7` does not have pip.

Install pip for your specific python by running `python3.7 -m easy_install pip`.

Then, install packages by `python3.7 -m pip install <package_name>`

Another option is to create a virtual environment from your python3.7. The venv brings pip into it by default.

You create venv by `python3.7 -m venv <venv_name>`

Comment: easy_install worked, but I could not run it because I did not have setuptools available, so I had to install it too, from sources because it did not work over the web. _ctypes library was not installed, and that I solved by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul. Then easy_install worked and I was able to use pip with 3.7

Answer (score 0):

I think the packages you install will be installed for the previous version of Python. I think you should update the native OS Python like this:

1. Install the python3.7 package using apt-get
   `sudo apt-get install python 3.7`
2. Add python3.6 & python3.7 to update-alternatives:
   `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.6 1`
   `sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.7 2`
3. Update python3 to point to Python 3.7:
   `sudo update-alternatives --config python3
4. Test the version:
   `python3 -V`