# How to use sudo command via PuTTY

Tags: python, django, linux, ssh, putty

I'm trying to depoly django app on a hosted server. My local PC has Windows as OS so I'm using PuTTY to connect to the server (which has GNU/Linux). Once I connect to the server, I install Python and setup vierualenv, but when i try to install the postgresql I receive the error

```
  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

I know that it's quite a common problem mentioned in numerous threads (for example, [Python3: ImportError: No module named '_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)) which can be solved by intalling "libffi-dev" by the command

```
sudo apt-get install libffi-dev
```

However, when I try to use the sudo command I receive the following error:

```
-bash: sudo: command not found
```

I tried to find a solution, but my experience with Linux is rather limited. From what I found, it may be caused by me not being logged as a superuser, but I could not find clear instruction how to enable it when I access Linux server via SSH (PuTTY) from Windows. Does anyone know a way how could access sudo command or how to install "libffi-dev" in a way which does not require sudo commands?Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Just curious, how did you install python without `sudo`? If you know the root password you can swap to root with `su -` and just run the command without `sudo` (and then maybe also install `sudo` with `apt`). If you don't have root access, you can maybe check [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/42567) - however I very much doubt this will solve your problem.

Comment: I conected to the host server by the admin password through PuTTY, and then istalled Python through the following bask commands:
'wget python.org/ftp/python/3.8.8/Python-3.8.8.tgz' 
'tar xvzf Python-3.8.8.tgz cd Python-3.8.8' 
'./configure --prefix=$HOME/.local' 
'make' 
'make install'
However, it does not install full package as during the "make" command I receive an notification: 
'failed to build there modules 
_ctypes'
 I heard that it could be installed manually by sudo commends, but they do not seem to be working. It also does not seem to recognise "su -" command

Comment: It sounds like you might be on a pretty restricted system or just not a "standard" out of the box linux setup. I would suggest posting a question on Unix & Linux site with more details about the OS and machine you're trying to do this on. Your problem isn't really a python issue it's more about working through your current system setup.