# Module Not Found Error: No module named '_ctypes'

Tags: fedora, python-3.10

I try to launch a python file but it returns me the error:

> File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ctypes/**init**.py", line 8, in 
> from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'

The only solution I found on the web is to:

`sudo dnf install libffi-dev`

I tried but it doesn't work either, although it seems to work for everyone.
If anyone has a lead...

Comment: This should help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to reinstall python:

```
pyenv uninstall <your_version>
sudo apt install libffi-dev
pyenv install <your_version>
pyenv global <your_version>
```

I had the same error and it helped.

Answer (score 4):

If you install Python3.7 from file, then reinstall it.

```
sudo apt install libffi-dev
cd Python-3.11.0a7
./configure --enable-optimizations
sudo make install
```

I had the similar error while using Python3.7 with venv and fixed as above.