# PyQt5 module not found, already compiled after installing (Mint)

Tags: python, pyqt5, linux-mint, compiled

I've the problem, that programs didn't run since PyQt5 is missing:

```
    from PyQt5.QtCore import (
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyQt5'
```

I've already installed PyQt5:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
python3-pyqt5 is already the newest version (5.14.1+dfsg-3build1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

and compiled with

```
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

but it didn't help.

Do you have any help for me? My OS is Linux Mint.

Comment: Why are you compiling when you've already installed the official Linux Mint PyQt5 packages?

Comment: I've commented since before that _ctypes has missed and it didn't work until I've compiled again.
It was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul) so I thought it may help here too.

Comment: Commented what? Commented where? And what has that got to do with your question (which is totally unclear)?

Comment: Sorry there's a typing mistake; I mean "I've compiled", not "I've commented"

Comment: It's still unclear what the problem is. If you're saying you have the official packages installed, but you cannot import PyQt5, that is something you need to report on the Linux Mint bug-tracker.