# CentOS7 Error running Python 3.9.0 Script _ctypes

Tags: python, pandas, linux, centos7, ctypes

I'm trying to run a python script from a virtual environment on CentOS.
My version of CentOS is the following:
CentOS Linux release 7.9.2009 (Core)

The script uses Python version 3.9.0 and the dependencies used are the following:

```
Package            Version
------------------ ---------
bcrypt             4.0.1
Bottleneck         1.3.7
certifi            2022.12.7
cffi               1.15.1
charset-normalizer 3.1.0
cryptography       40.0.2
et-xmlfile         1.1.0
idna               3.4
llvmlite           0.39.1
numba              0.56.4
numexpr            2.8.4
numpy              1.24.2
openpyxl           3.1.2
pandas             2.0.0
paramiko           3.1.0
pip                20.2.3
pycparser          2.21
PyNaCl             1.5.0
pyodbc             4.0.39
python-dateutil    2.8.2
pytz               2023.3
pyxlsb             1.0.10
requests           2.28.2
setuptools         49.2.1
six                1.16.0
tzdata             2023.3
urllib3            1.26.15
xlrd               2.0.1
```

When I try to run the script I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/www/aure/conexiont24.py", line 7, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from pandas.compat import is_numpy_dev as _is_numpy_dev  # pyright: ignore # noqa:F401
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from pandas.compat.numpy import (
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/compat/numpy/__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from pandas.util.version import Version
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/util/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from pandas.core.util.hashing import (  # noqa:F401
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/util/hashing.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.common import (
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/common.py", line 26, in <module>
    from pandas.core.dtypes.base import _registry as registry
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/dtypes/base.py", line 24, in <module>
    from pandas.errors import AbstractMethodError
  File "/var/www/aure/venv/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/errors/__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/ctypes/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_ctypes'
```

To fix the problem or get alternative solutions :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python3: ImportError: No module named '\_ctypes' when using Value from module multiprocessing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27022373/python3-importerror-no-module-named-ctypes-when-using-value-from-module-mul)

Comment: @MarceloPaco Hi, Nope, Previously try installing those dependencies but the error remains

Comment: Add more info as instructed in [\[SO\]: PyCharm doesn't recognize installed module (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73363599/4788546).